# Proposing a tag-synonym fails with a confusing error-message

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, tag-synonym-process

I tried to propose a synonym [make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) <= [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile).

That gave me the confusing error:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Reverse synonym makefile already proposed on the tag makefiles.

Which is a non-sequitur.

[As I recently learned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101611) from [m0sa♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/155005), disallowing the synonym is [status-bydesign].
Still, the error-message should be reverted to again be something like:

> A synonym from foo to bar exists, chains are not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments @pnuts is correct. Chains/hierarchies only worked for a [brief period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101611/156631), all of the existing ones [were created before August 2011](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/366924/tagsynonyms-hierarchies).

Comment: So, does that mean a moderator has to break the existing synonym to the tag I want to propose as a synonym first? The error-message does not even vaguely hint at that, which seems a regression.

Comment: yes, basically what you'd end up with in case your proposal goes through is `make<=makefile` and `make<=makefiles`

Comment: Modified the post to make it obvious there's still an error, though in the presentation.

Comment: @m0sa: Shouldn't **the error-message** be corrected?

Comment: @Deduplicator Can the error message even occur if the chains are done away with?

Comment: @jpmc26: If synonymizing a tag with synonyms stays forbidden, of course it will stay possible. Anyway, the (few existing) chains are not the problem, unless you use SEDE. And even then you can ignore them: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/357387/synonym-level