# Mjolnir doesn't work on old synonyms (should it?)

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, tag-synonym-process, dupehammer

One of the tags I participate in has 1 synonym that I proposed over 2 years ago.  The language in question offers 2 distinct syntaxes where the original one has the same name as the language, but the newer syntax became significantly more popular (so popular that a lot of people don't even realize the other one exists).  It was not uncommon to see a question about the language use the tag named after the other syntax, so I proposed the synonym.

A side effect of this is that there are still some old questions that have the pre-synonym tag on them.  I only have a gold badge in the base tag, not the synonym, which prevents me from closing old duplicates without the aid of other users.

Is this behavior intended?

Comment: Has the synonym been approved? What are the tags you are referring to?

Comment: Oh yes, the synonym was approved a long time ago.  The tag in question is [tag:sass] and the synonym is [tag:scss].

Comment: I went ahead and merged these; after two years, any problems with the synonym have passed the point where we can reasonably fix them anyway (and there don't seem to be any obvious ones)

Comment: Note that Mjölnir doesn't work on questions where the original tag set did not include your gold badge tag.  So, if a question was not originally tagged 'c' but that tag was later added, I can't wield Mjölnir (at least, not with the 'c' tag) to mark that question as a duplicate.  Mjölnir is powerful, but not all-powerful.

Comment: What is Mjolnir? I know it's from Norse mythology, but what does it have to do on this site? I saw it in the Hot Meta Posts section and clicked to see what it was about, figuring it was some tool on Stack Overflow, but I am no more enlightened. :-/

Comment: @Thunderforge: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/dupehammer/info

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is intended. If/when the tags are *merged*, then the synonym will be replaced by the target and this issue will go away.

Merging requires a moderator's intervention. There's an automatic list of tags that they consider on an irregular basis, but you can post [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)s if you feel a given tag needs more urgent attention.

Comment: Well I guess that leads to a follow-up question: why isn't that the default behavior for synonyms (merging)?

Comment: There's no undo. If some idiots decided to synonymize [tag:php] and [tag:javascript], there'd be an awful lot of cleanup... Realistically, bad merges are a headache even for fairly small tags - you wanna have some sanity checks involved in the process.

Comment: How does one tell that tags are merged as opposed to synonymized? Would you mind pointing out an example of merged tags?

Comment: Once tags have been merged, there are no questions in the source tag, @Josh. That's really the only difference - merging isn't so much a state as it is an action.

Comment: So if [dumplings] got merged into [biscuits], when I went to /questions/tagged/dumplings, I'd see an empty question list, instead of being redirected to /questions/tagged/biscuits as happens with synonyms?

Comment: Right. Unless they were *also* synonyms, in which case the behavior would be as normal for synonyms, @Josh. If you [visit the list of active synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=newest), anything with an " × number" in the second column hasn't been merged yet - the questions are just sorta orphaned.

Comment: Got it: it's more about the questions being merged than the tags themselves. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Well, the misguided person would be completely befuddled when blocked by the error-message: "Reverse synonym php-cgi already proposed on the tag php" when trying to synonymize php to js. [I asked about correcting the error-message.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306489/proposing-a-tag-synonym-fails-with-a-confusing-error-message)