# Are tags: [mutability] and [immutability] the same?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

(Edits at the bottom.)

### The Question

I was tagging a question with mutability and I noticed that there was a tag [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) and another one called [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability). The [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) tag has no wiki-description and was used 86 times, and the [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) does have a description and was used almost 1800 times.

I could be wrong, but these tags seems to be really similar to each other. A cursory look at questions tagged [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) shows that many of them are also tagged with [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability). That's like tagging [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) with [not-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-c) or [stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stability) with [unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unstable). Huh?

### Why Change?

Grammatically they're the same word, with a prefix. (See edit 2 below.)

In my mind [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) would generally refer to the idea of an object being mutable or immutable, similar to "stability" referring to something being stable or unstable. In other words, I would think that [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) would cover both cases. Except, of course, that the usage has mostly been the other way around - the numbers show a strong preference for [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability).

There are also two tags already mapped to [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability): Namely, [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutable) and [immutable-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutable-class). This makes sense, but all *three* tags fall under the umbrella concept of mutability, so shouldn't they all remap to a [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) tag with a proper wiki? This would cover mutability and immutability, providing a single tag to rule them all<sup>*</sup>.

A lot of the uses for [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) are asking about a particular situation where they want to know if something is immutable or how to make something that is [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutable) immutable.

I don't think someone looking to answer mutability questions is going to look only for situations where they are being asked if something is immutable, because... well... they're opposites. Both tags mean the same thing, from complementary perspectives.

### Proposed Resolution

What does the community think about combining them under [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability)?

I propose a wiki similar to the one in use for the immutability tag, but with broader scope, like so:

> Mutability is the idea that some pieces of data can be changed after creation. Such data is called "mutable." (Mut-able: It *can* be mutated.)
>
> Data that cannot be mutated after it has been created is said to be immutable. Modifications are instead made by copying the data. A property of immutable data is that it is *referentially transparent*.
>
> Mutability is a pattern found in many branches of programming; immutable objects are used widely within object oriented languages (*such as Python's `str` type, Java's `String` and `Integer` type, .NET's `System.String`, etc.*), functional programming (*esp. Haskell and other pure languages*), and other paradigms. The [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) framework has mutable and immutable versions of `NSArray`, `NSString` etc.

### Edit:

Some folks are positing that mutability and immutability have opposite meanings so they should be different tags.

I think a good way to consider this is from the perspective of a book index. Would mutability and immutability both be listed? Probably. But one entry would likely say "see {mutability}."

More extremely: There's no such thing as immutability. The correct word is mutability, which describes if an object is mutable or immutable.

### Edit 2:

I did some more research, and *immutability* is the same root word as *mutability*. The prefix `im` just means not. (See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117099/prefix-im-is-for-opposite-or-asserting) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1580/2019) on English.StackExchange.com)

As folks have pointed out, immutability is the term people run into more often because mutable is the default in many popular programming languages, so the tags are used "counter to" accepted grammar.

### Edit 3:

So it seems that there are a few arguments for either side. For my own benefit I'm going to try and put them here.

**For:**

1. The tags should be synonyms because they're often used together anyway.
2. Grammatically, they're the same word.

**Against:**

1. Many people are interested in making something immutable, and don't care about the opposite state, so the tag is useful on its own.
2. Grammar isn't a valid consideration here, we care about how people express their questions.

I think that there's something else to consider:

***Are tags there to express intent, or are they there to help users find questions of a given topic?***

If tags exist to express intent (*i.e. "I want to make something immutable," or "I want to learn about immutability in this context") then it makes sense to have two tags. I want to make something [stateful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stateful) in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), or I want to make something [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutable) in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

If tags exist to help people find questions, then a slightly more general tag covering both cases would help people answering find appropriate questions, and by extension help askers obtain answers. If we take a subject-driven approach, instead of an intent-driven approach, we find the appropriate tags to be [state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

The Stack Exchange Tour says:

> All questions are tagged with their subject areas. Each can have up to 5 tags, since a question might be related to several subjects.

It looks to me that tagging is for subject matter, not intent. If that's the case, and you agree with my assessment of the two sides here, then I think that synonym-izing is appropriate.

<sup>*where appropriate.</sup>

Comment: Grouping like that to a [java] or [.net] programmer makes as much sense as grouping [water] with [fire] because they are elements.  This does not need to be fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant would you please elaborate? I'm looking at this from a grammatical perspective for the most part. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think we'll just have to keep [immutability] around, since we can't make any changes to the posts tagged with it. :P

Comment: @HansPassant What sort of questions would you expect to be tagged "immutability" that should not also be tagged "mutability"?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your example. I think the site would greatly benefit from a [not-jQuery] tag.

Comment: A [tag:not-jquery] tag would probably be better served by [tag:javascript]. The point is that lots of things are often better described by their complementary opposite.

Comment: *I think a good way to consider this is from the perspective of a book index. Would mutability and immutability both be listed? Probably. But one entry would likely say "see {mutability}."* or simply "The opposite of {mutability}". I agree all the info would be at the positive case of the noun though

Comment: I have no strong opinion on this, but do wish to preemptively caution against including [tag:mutable] (a c++ keyword) in this discussion.

Comment: @Shog9 I didn't even notice that, but it's a good point.

Comment: @shog9 - That tag needs some work on the wiki, too - to call out that it's a keyword - if it isn't going to be dragged in here. (Kicking and screaming, of course.)

Comment: Well... yes and no.

Comment: I believe one reason immutability is used a lot more than mutability is that mutable state is the norm, while immutable is the peculiar thing. Hence people want to emphasize when they are dealing with the "special case", and thus immutability makes more sense. Also the term *immutability* **do** exists.

Comment: @Bakuriu just because a word is valid English doesn't mean it should be a tag on Stack Overflow. My phone's dictionary recognizes marathoning as a valid word. That doesn't make it a computer term. Immutability is the same way. The concept is called mutability. Can something be mutated? Well, it's mutability is either "yes, can be mutated" or "no, it's immutable." Very subtle difference but it exists.

Comment: @Moshe: You could argue the same way that the concept is called immutability, asking whether something doesn't change. There doesn't seem to be [much precedence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mutability%2Cimmutability%2C+mutable%2C+immutable&year_start=1500&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmutability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimmutability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmutable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimmutable%3B%2Cc0), however *immutable* is far more common than *mutable*.

Comment: @Bergi If you limit your query to the `...ability` forms being discussed and from 1950, when the term "computer" came into common use, you find the opposite to be true. But I don't think ngram viewer trumps grammar. The root word is mutable. immutable is a prefixed variant of it.

Comment: Note that [tag:mutable] also exists, separate from the other two. It was linked in the OP but it wouldn't be affected here.

Comment: Cursory glance says it's also a variant of mutability. 

Comment: @cimmanon: _What sort of questions would you expect to be tagged "immutability" that should not also be tagged "mutability"?_ [Questions about the semantics of immutable objects.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320873/are-tags-mutability-and-immutability-the-same?cb=1#comment333096_320956)

Comment: And the tag pedantry continues...

Comment: A better name for the question would have been "Is there an immutable difference between [mutability] and [immutability]?", or somesuch

Comment: So maybe the other was is more accurate. 

Comment: @DavidRR Except that we are discussing "immutability" vs "mutability", not "immutable" vs "mutable".

Comment: @cimmanon: Wikipedia redirects both "immutability" and "mutability" to "Immutable object", but that's about defining the concept. For actual implementation, they represent two different kinds of issues and approaches, depending on the default behaviour of the language or framework.

Comment: @corsair992 +1. Does that really make a difference? That's why there's [mutability] in [java] and [immutability] in [objective-c]. Are we tagging things because "implement this for me" or because "how does this work?"

Comment: @Moshe: The simple fact is that nobody cares about the general concept of the thing they're trying to implement, but the actual technical category of the implementation, and that is the only useful way to categorize things as well. As BJ Myers pointed out in his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320956), we have different tags for 'static' and 'dynamic' even though they are both opposite facets of the general concept of 'staticity' (or 'dynamicity'). Sure, tags for general concepts might have their place, but it makes no sense to sacrifice existing implementation related tags for them.

Comment: @corsair992 Tags are based on subject matter, not on "what do I need the internet to solve for me today?" That's a less extreme case of "give me teh codez" which we as a community said no to in the early beginnings of SO.

Comment: If you insist on merging these tags, choose the tag that is most common and most intuitive... immutability. You might not personally like it, but I think you need to respect the way language is actually used over the way you'd like language to be used in these kinds of scenarios. By your own research, the community has a pretty strong preference for immutability. (Do not construe this as agreement... I still strongly disagree with merging.)

Comment: @JDB - I'm not insisting on merging the tags, but if that were done, I definitely agree that usage plays a role in this.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265601/allow-for-tag-antonyms

Comment: Related: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29952106#29952106

Comment: @Moshe: If you look at it from an actual technical perspective, then these _are_ different subject matters. Mutability and immutability have different approaches for implementation, and someone may be interesting in just one of these. Tags exist to provide detailed categorization to facilitate both questions and answers, and I don't think there is any level of detail at which tagging shouldn't be implemented (we have tags for individual keywords, which I think is going a bit far). The point is that your suggestion removes information and granularity without providing any actual benefits.

Comment: @corsair992 That's fair, but how do we address the immutability questions that also have mutability? Most of mutability is like that.

Comment: @Moshe: [tag:mutability] is a small tag, I don't think you need to worry about it. It seems to have 78 questions at this time, 15 of which are also tagged with [tag:immutability]. In general, if a question concerns both of these things, then you could use either or both depending on what aspect you're focusing on (and possibly the relative number of subscribers as well).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339663/make-non-nullable-a-synonym-of-nullable

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am opposed to merging [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) into [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability).  If any synonimization or merging is to be done, **it should be the other way around**.

Both "mutability" and "immutability" are terms that describe the same attribute - either something is mutable (and therefore not immutable), or immutable (and therefore not mutable).  Hence the dictionary and "lightness vs. darkness" analogies used above.

But the term "immutable" is substantially more prevalent when discussing mutability.  Mutable objects are unremarkable; immutable objects are interesting.  This request is more like taking an "absolute zero" tag and merging it into a "temperature" tag.  Yes, something is either at absolute zero or not, but the former case is substantially more interesting.

The purpose of tags on SO is to make it easier for people to find questions and answers related to some topic.  In programming, "immutable" is so much more prevalent that it makes no sense to redirect people searching for "immutable" to its opposite.

(As an aside, try searching for [Mutable object](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mutable_object&redirect=no) on Wikipedia.  I'm not saying we have to follow Wikipedia's example - just pointing out that there is precedent for this.)

---

Regarding the dictionary argument - "static" and "dynamic" are opposites.  Should we merge those as well?  This is not a site about the English language - tags should be about terms as used in programming, not their Merriam-Webster origins.

Comment: Tagging is in a sense very much about the English language. It's how we find things on the site. I agree that it might be easier to search for immutable. Unlike static/dynamic or dark/light,  these are opposites stemming from the same word. One could pick either word and mean exactly the same thing. I wouldn't use static as a tag when I meant dynamic. Here's a question I asked 6 years ago, tagged [tag:static]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4124102/224988 [tag:dynamic] makes noticeably less sense here.

Comment: I agree - one could pick either word.  But most people pick "immutable" because that's the interesting case.

Comment: That's valid so maybe we should merge the tags the other way, as you suggested.

Comment: Since you are opposed to merging, could you give an example where a question would be tagged [immutability] that should not also be tagged [mutability] (or vice versa)?  Note that the question here is not about "mutable" vs "immutable".

Comment: I'm not necessarily opposed to merging, but if that does happen I think [immutability] should be the primary tag.

Comment: Your answer opens with "I am opposed to merging".  If you're opposed, there has to be a better reason for it than "I don't want to do it because that other guy wants to use a tag name I think is the wrong choice".

Comment: Or maybe instead of merging, we should synomymise [[tag:mutable]] to [[tag:mutability]] (and possible do a cleanup into a new [[tag:mutable-keyword]] where appropriate)

Comment: @cimmanon: If you're talking about the semantics of immutable objects, you would use [tag:immutability]; if about some semantics of _mutable_ objects, then [tag:mutability]. As BJ Myers stated, this is not an English language site, and as such descriptivity should not be sacrificed just because it's possible to group opposites under a general concept (as he suggested, you wouldn't want to use just 'staticity' or 'dynamicity' to group [tag:static] and [tag:dynamic], would you?)

Comment: @corsair992 I still don't see an actual example question here.  Questions discussing the "semantics of immutable objects" sounds like something that would belong over on CS.SE, not here.

Comment: @cimmanon: Replace 'semantics' with 'implementation' if you like. I'm sure you can find some examples if you look through the tags. Most languages are mutable by default, so implementing immutability is the issue, but some languages or frameworks might be the opposite.

Comment: @corsair992 But I am asking *you*, as the person who suggests that such a question exists and is appropriate for SO, to provide an example.  The burden of proof is on you.

Comment: @cimmanon: Since _you're_ the one who is proposing to merge two active tags, I would suggest that the burden of proof is on _you_ to establish that there doesn't exist any conceivable question where these tags would be useful as they stand. So far the only argument seems to be that it's grammatically appropriate, but this is not a grammar site, and I've shown that these tags could deal with different types of questions.

Comment: @corsair992 And while I'm at it, I'll prove that God doesn't exist either?

Comment: @cimmanon: Sure, if you're thinking of making a follow-up proposal to merge the [tag:god] and [tag:null] tags… 

Comment: Lol @corsair992 - not quite.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your answer really proposes. It starts with "I am opposed to merging", but continues with, in bold, "it should be the other way around" and finally "it would be better if these two tags were not merged". Could you clarify? Are you saying they shouldn't be merged or that they should be, but the other way around? This makes the voting on this answer a bit bizarre, because the initial answer was "do it the other way around".

Comment: To further Tunaki's point, the [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/320956/timeline) of this answer reveals that most of the upvotes were cast before the "don't do this edit" (see the daily voting breakdown).

Comment: I rolled this answer back to its original revision because the timeline revealed that all voting was for the original revision.  The subsequent edit completely negated the original voting on the post.  Others are of course free to simply vote on [JDB's contrary answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320981/4320665).

Answer (score 21):

The tags are not the same, though they are about the same subject.

You say:

> *I don't think someone looking to answer mutability questions is going to look only for situations where they are being asked if something is immutable, because... well... they're opposites.*

That's exactly the point.

If I'm working in a mutable language and wish to implement an immutable object, then I'm asking a question about [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability). That is, I need to implement immutability in an environment where that is not the norm and, thus, requires some effort. I need expertise specific to my environment and someone who understands immutability, what it means and what its purpose is. Examples:

- [Immutable.js: Data structure to represent 2D game field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36603998/211627)
- [ES2015 non-mutating array swap in React component (or flux action)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36427530/211627)

If I'm working in an immutable language and wish to implement a mutable object, then I'm asking a question about [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability). That is, I need to implement mutability in an environment where that is not the norm and, thus, requires some effort. I don't need someone who understands immutability... I've already got that. I need someone who knows how to implement mutability in an immutable language. There's a whole class of techniques designed for this scenario that are completely irrelevant in a mutable language (see [state monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad), as an example). Examples:

- [Understanding Mutability in F# : case study](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34688575/211627)
- [How does the Rust compiler know `Cell` has internal mutability?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33233003/211627)

It would make no sense to tag my question with [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) when it is *immutability* that I desire, and vice versa. The audience for each tag is different. If we were going to do merge these tags, then we'd have to merge [stateful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stateful) with [stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stateless). Yes, it's two sides of the same coin, but if my question is about "heads" then it doesn't make sense to tag my question with "tails".

I also disagree with your "intent" and "subject" dichotomy (edit #3). If I intend my subject to be about immutability (the inability to change), then it should be about immutability, not the opposite (the ability to change). "Able" and "unable" are not synonymous.

Comment: There's more nuance here than that, but if I can't articulate it well than maybe that's an issue.

Comment: @Moshe - If I can use a more specific word to more accurately describe what I want to do, why would a general one be better for the community? I don't think you've answered that in this case.

Comment: The concept is called mutability, regardless of whether it's turned on or off in a language by default. Stateful and stateless could he synonyms of state, by the same logic. The difference is that mutability happens to be the same word as the positive form, where as stateful and statefulness are different.

Comment: Because tags aren't "what I want to do" - that's what the question is for. Tags are for categorizing questions.

Comment: I think there's an important distinction that should be preserved. If I were programming in Javascript, then immutability is actually pretty hard to implement and I would want to use that more specific term. If I were programming in Haskel, then mutability is actually pretty hard and I would want to use that term. I don't see how combining them is beneficial to the community, and I would find it annoying. I agree that there's a bit of a void in the middle - if I wanted to discuss the topic of mutability in general, then there's not really a tag for that (like there is with state).

Comment: Adding the two letters to mutability contributes little, but it does cloud the tag options with two similar tags.

Comment: Merging shouldn't be about folding more specific terms into more general terms... it should be about associating synonymous terms, like vb and visual-basic. Otherwise we could merge most tags with "programming" and call it a day.

Comment: I don't think "immutability" is synonymous with "mutability" for the reasons already given.

Comment: No one is suggesting merging "immutable" with "mutable" (which would be analogous with "stateless" and "stateful"), the question is about "immutability" and "mutability".  How does immutability/mutability offer anything over immutable/mutable?

Comment: @cimmanon: As Shog9 [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320873/are-tags-mutability-and-immutability-the-same/320956?noredirect=1#comment332601_320873), [tag:mutable] is a specific C++ keyword, and [tag:immutable] seems to be a synonym of [tag:immutability].

Comment: @cinnamon I still don't see how the community benefits from merging more specific terms into less specific terms. Merging is supposed to be for synonyms, or that's how I've understood it. As an example, in Christian theology, one of God's traits is "immutability". It would be odd to have a lecture on the "mutability of God" where the lecturer advocates that God is immutable. The terms have technical meanings within that field. Similarly, I'd feel like a question about making a JS object immutable should be tagged "immutability", not "mutability", for the same technical reasons.

Comment: Actually, @JDB, I think that that title *is* appropriate for that lecture. It's the same way we call `Truth tables` what we call them, despite the possibility of a table that's got only false values in it. Does that make it a "Falseness" table?

Comment: @Moshe Ngram would [disagree](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Mutability+of+God%2CImmutability+of+God&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMutability%20of%20God%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CImmutability%20of%20God%3B%2Cc0) with you on that.

Comment: @Moshe Obviously theology is irrelevant to this discussion. The general point is that, within a particular field, words that would normally be nearly synonymous can take on significant individual meaning, to the point that they are no longer synonymous. Whether or not that's the case here is up to personal opinion, but my opinion is that *is* the case and that these words, within the field of computer science and programming, should not be considered synonymous.

Comment: @JDB understood re: theology not being relevant. I updated the post with some more food for thought.

Comment: If there was a truth-table tag, it would represent discussion about using truth tables, operating on both the true and false values in them.  Conversely, an imaginary false-table tag could still be about truth tables, but specifically discussing ways to avoid using them, bypass them, etc..  That is more analogous to mutability/immutability, where both share subject matter, but represent very different expertise and mutually exclusive applications of the concept.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the proposal of merging [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) with [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability).  Mutability encompasses whether a variable is mutable or immutable.  We discussed this in chat, and the [best analogy we came up with for the request is this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29908154#29908154):

> He wants to synonimize [darkness] into [lightness]

I suspect the popularity of [immutability] over [mutability] stems from users not actually reading the tags they're using and "immutability" was close enough to "immutable" that they just went with it.

Comment: why merging instead of a synonym? from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work), "As merging is not (easily) reversible, it should be done with caution and only when a synonym is established."

Comment: Why *not* merging?  The words convey the exact same meaning despite their root words having opposite meanings (eg. opaque and transparent are opposites, but increasing the opacity of something is decreasing its transparency).  Note that pre-synonym questions will not be eligible for closure via mjolnir (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307207/mjolnir-doesnt-work-on-old-synonyms-should-it)

Comment: Well, at least because of the "only when a synonym is established" requirement. Synonyms should be merged anyway eventually.

Comment: "*I suspect the popularity of [immutability] over [mutability] stems from users not actually reading the tags*" sounds unlikely to me. I'd guess they just entered [immutable], which resolved to [immutability] automatically. Btw, there's nothing wrong with the term "immutability" either.

Comment: _"I suspect the popularity of [immutability] over [mutability] stems from users not actually reading the tags"_ - No, the popularity of [immutability] is due to the popularity of the term as used by programmers.  The primary reason for talking about "mutability" is when you're talking about making something immutable.

Comment: @BJMyers And as you point out in [your answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320956/1497596), on Wikipedia, "Mutable object" redirects to ["Immutable object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Answer (score -9):

Mutable is typical and clear, so if you ask, you probably going to make something immutable.

And you found 1800 [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) questions over 86 [mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutability) ones.

Seems clear enough that it shouldn't move in most cases so use [immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/immutability) as primary.

Comment: Everything is *not* mutable.  Haskell is one such language where being immutable is the norm, and being mutable is the rare case.

Comment: In Python tuples are immutable. In Erlang, bound variables are immutable. This answer makes no sense.

Comment: @Tommy, then why there are 1800 questions about immutability, and less then a hundred about mutability?

Comment: because of the exact reason @bj_myers said. You wouldn't tell someone "I can breathe" because it is uninteresting and the norm. But you would certainly try to say "I can't breathe" because that is far more.. interesting. Please note that your original answer had "Everything is mutable", which you have now removed, and I was replying to your original answer.

Comment: @Tommy, right. But then why use first way for tagging? By the way, I updated the first sentence.

Comment: your new answer is now the same as BJ Myers's answer and in that case I agree. also this picture, while mildly amusing, does not really help anything.

Comment: @Tommy, it was my original idea, seems like I've badly expressed it. I ment "everything" like everithing in daily life, things that you see, but not as any programming structure is mutable.

Comment: @JDB, you are free to remove it.