# Make [non-nullable], [nullable] and [nullability] synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I think [non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-nullable) and [nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullable) should be synonyms of [nullability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullability). I would suggest it myself, but I don't have a score of 5 in the tags.

Although the first two terms are *antonyms* as English words, rather than *synonyms*, as tags they cover the same programming feature, [nullability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullability). It's like if there were tags for [true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/true) and [false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/false), they would mean the same as [boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boolean) to describe a question.

Comment: On the face of it, this seems like an absurd proposal. You want to synonymize something with its polar opposite? Why should we do that?

Comment: @TinyGiant, reasoning was added. But with a -6 score, I'm making my most pitiful entrance to meta

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, but some languages have specific 'non-nullable' features, like Java with `@NonNull` or C# with the `string! foo` proposal. So certain questions could benefit from having that tag.

Comment: If they both cover the same concept of nullability, why not make a new tag with that name, and synonym both to it?

Comment: @TinyGiant I've modified the question to take into account your good suggestion