# Merge some opposite tags

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Should we merge some opposites?

- [unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unmarshalling) into [marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marshalling) (263 have *both* tags)
- [deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deserialization) into [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization) (1849 have *both* tags)
- [decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decoding) into [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding) (465 have *both* tags)

I'm sure there's more, but I don't see why we need opposite tags. It just creates confusion given that there are over 2500 questions that have the complete set of tags to represent 2 sides of the same coin.

We already have done [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption) with [decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decryption), etc. See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/synonyms

Comment: Of course not.  The "creates confusion" theory is a pretty odd one.  If it actually does then it has to be useful, the OP most certainly would not want an answer from anybody that is confused like that.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry that i wasn't clear. thanks english. the confusion comes to the OP trying to figure out what to tag and if it takes 2 tags to describe the 2 sides of the same coin, then that's a problem.

Comment: I have no clue about `marshalling` but the other two could have distinct issues which are only present in one direction and not the other.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus but wouldn't the umbrella cover it? for instance decoding something requires something that is encoded

Comment: Starting from "decod" there are `decode`, `decoding`, `decoder`, `encoder-decoder` and various less relevant choices. How many do you propose to merge? Are you suggesting an umbrella, e.g. `encoding-decoding`, or synonyms, e.g. `encoding` with `decoding` as a synonym?

Comment: @HABO I propose to go the positive route like how encryption is done

Comment: [tag:non-nullable] into [tag:nullable] (see [my first question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339663/make-non-nullable-nullable-and-nullability-synonyms))

Comment: Unless tags could be part of sub tags (and this is not wanted by SO community) I don't see how this is going to do any good. Weird enough, there are some experts at serialization that do not know much about de-serialization. And vice versa. I'll give you one point though, since the maximum tag on questions has been set to 5... IMO, might as well regroup more than divide.

Comment: @DanielA.White I honestly do not know. Based on the upvotes on my comment I would guess that people feel the need to keep them differentiated.

Comment: *"We already have done encryption with decryption, etc."* - can't find a link to meta, can you please provide one? To me idea looks stupid same as reasoning so I want to read about it (and possible downvote questions and answers there). Here is another reason for you: less tags. Why? No idea, because "why not" (sarcasm)? If I ask a question about deserialization issue (assuming I have shown correct input file), I don't want answers with serialization. Nor I want my search to be clogged with serialization questions. I am looking for **de**-serialization. Let me please.

Comment: @Sinatr i'm not saying there was a meta issue for it, but the work was done: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/synonyms