# The tag [non-nullable] and [nullable] should be synonyms of [nullability]

Tags: feature-request, synonym-request

I am reasking [Make [non-nullable], [nullable] and [nullability] synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339663/16217248) because the old question originally asked a different question (Make [non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-nullable) synonym of [nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullable)) so the voting on the old one is [muddied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56372214#56372214).

The tags are opposites but of the same idea. A pointer or reference can be nullable or nonnullable. This status is called nullability. Only [nullability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullability) is required to cover any questions currently tagged by either [non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-nullable) or [nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullable). I am requesting both to be made synonyms of [nullability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullability).

Please also note that [nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullable) has a decent tag wiki and excerpt and the others have none, so if [nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullable) is made a synonym of [nullability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullability), also be sure to preserve the tag wiki somehow.

Comment: My original question went from -6 to +8. I wonder if I got a badge for that. :P

Comment: @Cœur If there was an answer while the question was -2 or lower, they could have gotten the lifeboat badge if the answer scored 10.