# What can be done to prevent [gas] tag ambiguity?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Currently, [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) tag refers to gnu-assembler.  However, it can also be inferred as relating to [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), a scripting solution to automate Google products such as Google sheets.

New users frequently tag [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) to refer to Google apps script. This creates the tag editing burden on the community.

- [Current data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1263135/1555542/how-many-questions-associated-with-tag1-was-changed-to-tag2#messages) shows that 200 questions in [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) was mistagged and retagged later to [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). Given that [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) has only 756 questions, this represents **20% of all [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) questions , if they were not mistagged.**
- [Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1263134/1555541/) shows ~1800 questions in [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) has the word "gas" in either the title or the body, compared with ~300 questions in [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas). Relative to total questions in each tag(33k vs 0.7k), it can be argued that "gas"'s accuracy is high in [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas), but "gas" is meant to mean "google-apps-script" 6 times more than "gnu-assembler" in absolue  numbers(1800 vs 300) and therefore much more common.
- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) is around 40 times popular than [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) by number of questions(33000 vs 756).
- [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) currently has

  - 258 watchers.
  - 5 questions in the last 30 days
  - 2 answerers this month.
  - Tag trend:[Data](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/fa64f4e31fa017ad835568e5228b4f84) from [Tanaike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) [image]
- Relatively, [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) has

  - 6.4k watchers
  - 807 questions in the last 30 days
  - >20 answerers this month
  - Tag trend:[Data](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/fd7dbc6d630fd0550c32159635cecc96)  from [Tanaike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)
    [image]
- The declining trend after 2016 and low absolute popularity of [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas), compared to [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) ,would mean mistagged questions remain mistagged for a long time rather than if it were the other way around. More users would mean easy and efficient fixing of mistagged questions. At 20% of the  total questions in [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas), this is a significant burden on the tag editors.

The previous proposals and discussions can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397525/rename-gas-to-gnu-assembler) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398344/improving-google-apps-script-tags-tag-wikis-and-excerpts#comment779085_398818), but none seems to have gained any traction.

Kindly suggest better or efficient solutions to the problem and how to accelerate  any action that needs to be taken as the issue is dormant for almost a year now.

My suggestion:

- Rename [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler)(same as previous requestors) and either

  - Make [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) **OR**
  - Ban [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) outright to prevent ambiguity

But at this point, any action is welcome.

Comment: *New users frequently tag [tag:gas] to refer to Google apps script.* This is the problem that needs to be solved. The tag excerpt for [tag:gas] doesn't even mention Google Apps Script.

Comment: We have no ability to ban tags outright (i.e., blacklist) anymore, unfortunately. So that option is right out. I am, as I said before, not comfortable with the claim that “gas” is more commonly used to mean Google’s something, versus the Gnu assembler, for which it is *very* commmonly used, even as the name of the executable itself, and *clearly* on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for the response.1.Given that new users can't create tags, once [gas] is gone, it might not come back.2. About the accuracy of the name "gas", Even if it as you say,  in absolute terms,because of the overall popularity, more users would refer to apps script as gas. I made a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1263134/1555541/) to see  how many times the word "gas" is associated with the tag, The query returns ~1800 for apps-script and ~300 for gnu tag.  Percent wise, gnu might appear top.But sheer absolute numbers would mean more  burden on editors.

Comment: My point is that the number of watchers in gas tag would not be able to handle the absolute number of mistagged questions and the mistagging is only set to increase.

Comment: @CodyGray - despite a lot of arguments for doing something about the tag are related to the popularity, maybe a more pragmatic approach could be adopted - I know you are uncomfortable with the proposal, but if it solves more issues than it creates, why not? For example, we have a huge problem with 35 char limit that is not going anywhere soon and this short version can help a lot. Just a rename can help a lot - people will start to get used to the tag being named that way, and eventually the need for [tag:gas] will naturally diminish. Then it can by made synonym then...

Comment: ...also, [tag:gnu], as you know, has a lot of branching : [tag:gnu-coreutils], [tag:gnu-findutils], [tag:gnu-sort], [tag:gnu-make], [tag:gnu-toolchain], [tag:gnu-smalltalk], [tag:gnu-prolog], etc., so isn't it kind of expected to have [tag:gnu-assembler] as well, why GAS? That said, I do realize that it is commonly refered to as `gas` or `as`, and that is a valid point

Comment: @oguzismail - I apologize if the query comes off as showing "newbies misuse", the intention was to show that the current wording creates issues while preventing optimizations to be made in other tags, leading to subpar experience for both parties.

Comment: @oguzismail I dont think I made my point clear. The query was intended to gauge the usage of a word "gas" within body/title in  questions associated with a tag. This is in direct response to the  statement by cody: *not comfortable with the claim that “gas” is more commonly used to mean Google’s something, versus the Gnu assembler*. The results show "gas" is used 1800 times with [tag:google-apps-script] and 300 times with [tag:gas].  In absolute numbers, "gas" is "more commonly" used to mean [tag:google-apps-script].

Comment: @oguzismail As said before, I meant gnu-assembler tag. This  discussion isn't just for the benefit of apps script users, but also for [tag:gas] users. Mistagged questions will be more and watchers aren't enough/will not be enough in [tag:gas] to handle retagging. For eg, [the first proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397525/rename-gas-to-gnu-assembler) was made by a user active in the gnu-assembler tag and not the apps script tag.

Comment: Whilst GAS is a common abbreviation both for GNU assembler and Google-Apps-Script, on Stackoverflow there are way more questions about Google Apps Script than GNU assembler. So it makes more sense to make GAS a tag for Google Apps Script.

Comment: @oguzismail - hence my comment about the pragmatic side of things: [tag:gas] leads to more problems than it solves: 1. Extra work for editors. 2. Less visibility for questions that go unnoticed until someone on the lookout decides to check. 3. It is dissonant with other GNU-based tags. And that's only the tip of the iceberg. Please also note that the problem can be solved without taking the tag, just a rename will be a good progress. 
P.S. Popularity is just an argument addressing ongoing discussion with Cody.

Comment: "Google Apps Scripts is a very long name for such a popular technology, so it's expected for askers to abbreviate it" is literally an argument *for* the adoption of `gas` to mean Google Apps Script, not against. It's expected that people will call it this. People inherently do not like change, but much like spoken language, when a word becomes so synonymous with a new concept, the old meaning starts to be overshadowed. While gas is commonly used to mean both, the use cases are clearly reflected by the popularity of one meaning over the other, and Stackoverflow should reflect this.

Comment: @oguzismail *Personally I am still willing to keep removing the gas tag from questions about Google Apps Script and downvoting them for bothering me* You say that, but you're not in the top questioners or answers in [tag:gas]. There are [no posts associated with you and tag:gas](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A10248678+%5Bgas%5D). I highly doubt your willingness to bear the tag editing burden.  Also [tag:gas]  is only a year old than [tag:google-apps-script]

Comment: @oguzismail If we take this stance then the fact that new users can ask questions at all without being forced to understand how the tags work is the root of the problem. It's intractable and non-mitigatable. This is about making things as clear as possible for new users, while minimising work on established users with constant tagging and retagging.

Comment: It would be really nice if SO had tag-combination checking, like `[gas]` + `[google-sheets]` gave a warning, or `[gas]` *without* `[assembly]` gave a warning.  I don't follow the GAS or NASM tags specifically, just `assembly` and `x86*`, because I expect people to tag "assembly" for question about assembly languages.  IDK, maybe I should follow them as well, but I'm more interested in the machine / ISA than the asm syntax.

Comment: @oguzismail - wait, you downvote the question just for mistagging an ambigous tag..? Re:gnu - actually, this has more to do with the larger discussion of "branching" tags vs "constructor" tags (for example, see [`git`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266221/can-we-get-rid-of-git-something-tags/266254#266254)). I mentioned it since [tag:gnu-assembler] will perfectly fit in line with other GNU-linked tags. Even though we debate the [tag:gas] part, the rename to [tag:gnu-assembler] is not in dispute, it would be a good solution given the very limited abilities we have now

Comment: We have many other commonly-mistagged tags, like SSE for server-sent-events.  It really annoys me when people tag *both* SSE and server-sent-events because they obviously found both tags but then just assumed there were redundant tags instead of reading the popups.  Also `[mars]` (some library) is commonly mistagged for `[mars-simulator]` (the MIPS simulator).  The GAS case sounds worse than most.

Comment: Either `gnu-gas` or `gnu-assembler` are better than `gas`, rename away by me.

Comment: @PeterCordes - true, as I am sure you know the outcry for a feature like this has been around for ages, but alas to no avail... Having a warning would be a solution close to ideal, if not the solution. This is sort of possible, but I recall info that it needs to be manually added by an employee, which makes it intractable... Re:[tag:mars] - it could potentially be fixed by a rename with `mssql-` prefix (given that there already are tags with that prefix)

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 Asa top questioner and answerer of the tag [tag:gas], your opinion  is valuable. Consider creating a answer. Thank you for accepting my invite  and your comments on the matter.

Comment: @CodyGray - could you take a look at the renaming of [tag:gas] if you have some time to spare? We asked the top answerers from the tag to weigh in, and there is no dissonance between us in that renaming and synonymization process should proceed. I think top answerers from respective tags being in agreement should be enough to address the concern of name usage (at least the renaming part of things - that would be a start). This will solve many problems for both sides and close a long-standing issue. Thank you for considering this!

Comment: @CodyGray Also tagged Bhargav He seems ok with making a synonym as well if there are no dissenting opinions among subject experts.  We waited a few days to see if there are dissenting opinions raised. There was none from any side. I'm sure you'd respect subject matter experts opinion in respective tags. Let me know if you still have any reservations.

Comment: TheMaster: Pinging moderators about this is very annoying. We have other things to do, most of which are more important than manipulating some tags. (For example, have you noticed there's an election going on?) Having the requests on Meta is sufficient. They don't need to be fast-tracked to our inboxes. We review the Meta requests whenever we have the opportunity, assuming they are properly tagged. Creating even more posts on Meta about the same thing doesn't help fast-track it, either. It just accomplishes annoying a moderator. (cc @Oleg)

Comment: @CodyGray Apologies. I wanted to wait till after the election. But since I saw another  comment (by oleg), I thought you would want to read it in the same note(about bhargav which happened a while back) without having to annoy you later.  The intention was to avoid annoying you. Apologies again.

Comment: @CodyGray - I apologize if that was too much. This post was meant to be a definitive discussion about the tag's future, and since you provided the input on this from the start pinging you in the comments sounded like a good idea. If there was something like "we will get back to it after the election" note or something similar we would not worry too much about it and just rest for a while. You also mentioned that a lot of times notifications get drowned under an avalanche of others.

Comment: ...and please do forgive us for being overly concerned about not a very important problem per se - this tag discussion is blocking several others that we could resolve by ourselves. To wrap up: we do understand that there is an election going on, there are only so many of you and that you do a huge amount of mostly thankless work, and it is really appreciated that you still take time to disambiguate/retag/rename/merge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I spent some time reviewing all the related Meta posts, chats, and their associated comments on this matter and I'm willing to add my views.

I do agree with much of Peter Cordes said and most especially the idea of having tag combination checking. That would help with the [boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boot), [bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootloader), [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly), [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot), [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) mess.

I had observed that there was an argument about whether GAS was what we call GNU Assembler. The short answer is yes. It has been called GAS for longer than Google has existed. The [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) tag is very appropriate as the short form of GNU Assembler. I've been using GNU Assembler since my university days 30 years ago when I was doing some VAX and PDP development. I didn't start using the term GAS in discussions until Linux started become popular in the mid 1990s.

With that being said, I have no problem with Stackoverflow changing things based on the volume and popularity of questions associated with [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). The current usage [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) for GNU Assembler is infrequently used in comparison.

The one thing I will not accept as a tag for GNU Assembler is [gnu-gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-gas) and hope that can be taken off the table as GNU GNU will make me do a double take every time I see it.

My preference is to retag all [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler) and make [gnu-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-as) a synonym. I fully support seeing [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) being used for [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). I believe that [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) should exist as a tag, and it should be associated with [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) instead. The only thing I would ask is that the tag excerpt for [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) direct GNU assembler (GAS) questions to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler).

Comment: `The only thing I would ask is that the tag excerpt for [gas] direct GNU assembler (GAS) questions to [gnu-assembler].` This is important and I agree that it should be done at least for the forseeable future.

Comment: If "*`gnu-gas` … will make me do a double take every time I see it*, do you get stuck in an infinite recursion loop every time you see "GNU"?

Comment: @RayButterworth: I hit that Stackoverflow first ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I like short tag names, but since this is becoming a large problem I think renaming `[gas]` to `[gnu-assembler]` is a good choice.  I don't have an opinion on banning `[gas]` vs. making it a synonym of the more popular tag.

I considered `gnu-gas`, but that creates some mental dissonance: The G in GAS already stands for GNU.  It's GNU `as`, the GNU assembler, not GNU gas.  I think it would be annoying to see that everywhere.  As a bonus, `gnu-as` should auto-complete to gnu-assembler.

OTOH, `gnu-gas` would pop up as a completion if you type `gas` in the tag box, so it might be slightly more transparent for people who missed the news about the tag rename.  But it's such an unpopular tag that that's not a big consideration.

---

We have many other commonly-mistagged tags, like SSE for server-sent-events. It really annoys me when people tag both SSE and server-sent-events because they obviously found both tags but then just assumed there were redundant tags instead of reading the popups. Also `[mars]` (some library) is commonly mistagged for `[mars-simulator]` (the MIPS simulator).

It would be really nice if SO had tag-combination checking, like `[gas]` + `[google-sheets]` should give a warning, or `[gas]` without `[assembly]` gave a warning.  But until that ever gets implemented, I guess we need to avoid simple convenient tag names. :(

---

I didn't previously follow the GAS or NASM tags specifically, just `assembly` and `x86*` and a few others, because I expect people to tag "assembly" for question about assembly languages.  But I just added those to my list of tags in my custom filter, since I do a lot of re-tagging anyway.  I might unfollow `gas` if it gets annoying dealing with questions from people who don't bother to read their tags; SSE is bad enough at maybe 1 or 2 a week that I fix, with more fixed by a few other users.

Comment: As the top most answerer in the tag, your insights are most valuable. *gnu-as should auto-complete to gnu-assembler.* Maybe we should name it [tag:gnu-as] and add [tag:gnu-assembler] as it's synonym. It's short and apt.

Comment: I think reduntant `G`s aren't so much of a concern for `GNU` ;)

Comment: In case some people don't get it, Rafa Guillermo's comment is referring to the fact that the "G" in "GNU" stands for "GNU".

Answer (score 10):

#### Summary of the current situation:

- The tag [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) currently refers to GNU Assembler.
- The abbreviation [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) refers to both [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) *and* [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler) for users of both technologies
- There exists no tag nor tag synonym for [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler)
- [gnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu) is [already a common tag branch for GNU Utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-make+or+gnu-screen+or+gnu-parallel+or+gnu-coreutils+or+gnu-toolchain+or+gnu-smalltalk+or+gnu-prolog+or+gnu-findutils+or+gnu-arm+or+gnu-global+or+gnu-common-lisp+or+gnu-efi+or+gnu-sed+or+gnu-sort+or+gnu-indent+or+gnu-classpath+or+gnu-apl+or+gnu-fileutils+or+gnu-date+or+gnu-install)
- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) *also* [has a lot of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-web-application+or+google-apps-script-addon+or+google-apps-script-editor+or+google-apps-script-simple-triggers+or+google-apps-script-api+or+google-apps-script-html-service+or+google-apps-script-runtime+or+google-apps-script-libraries+or+google-apps-script-menu+or+google-apps-script-dashboard+or+google-apps-script-project) which use the base tag as the prefix
- From the original question: *[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) is around 40 times popular than [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) by number of questions(33000 vs 756)*

  - Adding to this, [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) has had **123 times** the number of questions asked for [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) in the last 2 weeks (**3** questions for [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) compared to **368** questions for [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)).
  - API Query for [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) is [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1593561600&todate=1594771200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=gas&page=1), query for [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) spans 4 pages [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1593561600&todate=1594771200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=google-apps-script&page=1), [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1593561600&todate=1594771200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=google-apps-script&page=2), [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1593561600&todate=1594771200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=google-apps-script&page=3) and [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&fromdate=1593561600&todate=1594771200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=google-apps-script&page=4)

#### Issues with the current situation:

- Given the [gnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu) prefix for the branch of all other GNU tool tags, [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) is out of place and causes confusion.
- *There exists no tag nor tag synonym for [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler)*
- The current method for branching [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) related tags is broken:

  - [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) is aleady 18 characters, making using it as a prefix either inconsistent or downright impossible for branched tags which are 16 characters in length (18 for `google-apps-script` plus 1 extra for the subsequent `-` to keep kebab case)
  - [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) is already commonly used and has multiple branches which use [gs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gs) as a prefix, eliminating the ability to use this without introducing additional confusion

**Correctness is not the only argument for or against a tag's usage:**

While it is true that GNU assembler has been around for a lot longer than Google Apps Script, the use of the abbreviation `gas` is outweighed by a landslide in favour of Google Apps Script over GNU Assembler. As is the nature of technology, changes are rapid and the adoption of similar or identical names and abbreviations is somewhat inevitable given enough time. To speak philosophically, tradition does not outweigh evolution.

People inherently do not like change, but much like spoken language, when a word becomes so synonymous with a new concept, the old meaning starts to be overshadowed. While `gas` is currently commonly used to mean both GNU Assembler *and* Google Apps Script, the use cases are clearly reflected by the popularity of one meaning over the other, and Stackoverflow should reflect this. It is important moving forward that things as clear as possible for new users, while minimising work on established users with constant tagging and retagging.

#### Solution Proposal:

- [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) should be renamed to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler), in line with the other GNU utility tags already on the site.
- [gnu-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-as) could/should be made a synonym of [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler).
- [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) should be used as a synonym for [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), reducing retagging work for established users and frequenters of both [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) and [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), while also opening the door for a more consistent branching of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) related tools.

  - Given the above proposals, the [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) excerpt needs clarification for its use - Either a warning or simply starting with `FOR GNU ASSEMBLER QUESTIONS USE THE [gnu-assmebler] TAG` should be sufficient for reduciung erroneously tagged questions.

Comment: I don't think we need a `gnu-as` tag; when actually tagging, it will autocomplete to `gnu-assembler`.  In other contexts, like when searching, I don't think it's too hard to type a somewhat longer tag name.

Comment: Also the "gas" term is related to blockchain / ethereum - [What is gas?](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027772571-What-is-gas-). I just removed this tag from two questions related to blockchain / ethereum. (see the chat linked to this question for details)

Answer (score 6):

[gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) is now renamed to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler). [gnu-as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-as) is a synonym of [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler).

Tag blacklists are no longer really an option, unfortunately. I'm going to suggest we try leaving it for a while with [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) non-existent and seeing what happens. Since there are no `[gas*]` tags, *hopefully* someone will think twice about creating it? Maybe? Well, I'm going to hope against hope. We might need to go back and make [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) a synonym of [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), but I'd kinda rather not do that unless we have to.

Comment: First Thank you :) *Since there are no [gas\*] tags hopefully someone will think twice about creating it? Maybe?* Well, Well I hope you don't get angry. But we already created [tag:gas-web-app] a synonym of [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] 2 weeks back because, [tag:gas-web-app] has zero ambiguity: our reasoning was [gnu-assembler] has nothing to do with [web-apps], So it won't be mistagged. We were also considering splitting up to [google-apps-script] and [web-application], but the status of [web-applications] itself was in [limbo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399422)

Comment: @The I saw that, and I already reversed the direction so that the main tag is [[tag:google-apps-script-web-application]], and [[tag:gas-web-app]] is a synonym of it. (I don't think you could do that, as regular users, since the latter tag was more popular. But mods can make synonyms go in either way.)

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thank you. Just asking for your opinion Do you think it'll be better to split it up?

Comment: You're talking about splitting up [web-application]? I have no idea. Maybe, but that's a *huge* exercise, and I'm not sure it's really worth the time/effort.

Comment: No about tag [google-apps-script-web-application]. It is a long tag=> would split to tag is [google-apps-script][web-application] be worth it? Currently I think I and ruben are tagging this tag retrospectively(I more)

Comment: Oh, uh... I don't think [web-application] is a very good tag. It seems to be huge, broad, and almost meaningless. What *isn't* a web application these days (aside from everything I do, but you get the point)? :-) I think it makes more sense to plan for [web-application]'s eventual removal. What is it really gaining you to have that tag on questions?

Comment: Apps script runs server side. So all questions are mostly server side. But web-apps is a client side a niche in apps script. Questions here mainly target client-server communication and Google's injected scripts, where Google sandbox-iframe our html/js content. This creates sandbox restrictions and questions mostly about that.

Comment: @TheMaster, I don't think we should go the [tag:web-application] route either (bet we will attract a lot of generics that we will have to retag), but how about renaming [tag:gas-web-app] to simply [tag:web-apps] ( to Cody: this is literally how it is officially called: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web ) and using it with our main tag name [tag:google-apps-script] as a possible solution?

Comment: @OlegValter You mentioned that before. But that'll have exactly the same effect as renaming [web-applications] to [web-apps]. Wiki may differ, but that will be the only difference.

Comment: @Oleg I just don't think I can agree to naming the tag something as generic as [web-apps], and I don't think *you* want that, either. You'll get everybody and their dog who is trying to develop a web app cluttering your tag. It'd be worse than a [gas] tag on an automobile maintenance Q&A site...

Comment: @CodyGray, TheMaster - yeah, I know... Same goes for [tag:web-application], that's what probably will happen regardless of the form (unless it has a `google-apps-script-*` or `gas-*` prefix as it has currently), the naming itself is flawed ( the bizzare concept behind it does not help either ). I am good with the current state of affairs

Comment: @CodyGray Could you kindly undo the synonymization [gas-web-app]=>[google-apps-script-web-application] instead? The only reason synonym was done is to have a smaller tag. We can't propose any synonym of this tag anywhere. It says ``Reverse synonym google-apps-script-web-application already proposed on the tag gas-web-app``. Thank you

Comment: @The I'm sorry, I don't understand your justification here. It seems you created that synonym yourself, mapping [[tag:gas-web-app]] to [[tag:google-apps-script-web-application]]. Why should it be undone? You didn't create "a smaller tag"; the master tag was always the longer one. And there's no real advantage in a shorter tag anyway.

Comment: [gas-web-app] was the master tag and you told us you reverse synonymized it.There are real advantages to the shorter tag. I and a few others lately [discussed the issue in a room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50179941#50179941) and We wanted to make [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] slave of [tag:web-applications] or the main tag: [google-apps-script]. When suggesting synonym for voting, We ran into this issue of  "chaining", which we weren't aware. Now that [*-html-service] is also synonymized( because we weren't aware), We aren't sure how to absorb this tag.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about. I don't know about any issues with "chaining". How did [\*-html-service] also get synonymized? I feel like either I'm missing a *lot* of background, or you're somehow making a mess of the tagging system. I distinctly remember saying elsewhere that I'm opposed to making [web-applications] a synonym of some Google-specific tag. That hasn't changed. I don't see any advantages to a shorter tag. Longer tags are generally better, as they're more descriptive. It's best to avoid acronyms and abbreviations, since they inexorably lead to clashes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow this post. [See chaining](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306489/proposing-a-tag-synonym-fails-with-a-confusing-error-message). Basically, creating [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] was a mistake. A generic [web-application] tag should be enough to categorize or search the question.But I not only created the tag, but retagged most of them. See https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1274673/1570416 and https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1264905/1557920. 80% of questions were basically result of retagging(54%by me)

Comment: I thought it warranted a separate tag then. [google-apps-script-web-application] is nothing but Google-apps-scriot on server side and a hosted webpage on the client side. I thought the iframe was unique and made the tag. I realize I made a mistake. Most of the questions about web-apps are not actually tagged with [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] and no new user seems to be  doing it either. It was all after answering>we retag it. It's better to just let users use a generic tag like [web-application] ,if they want to or just the main tag [google-apps-script] should be enough.