# Tag rename: [mars] to [ms-sql-mars], so [mars] can be about the MIPS simulator

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [MARS freeware MIPS simulator / IDE](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/) is widely used by students learning MIPS assembly language. It provides a set of system calls for the toy  MIPS environment it simulates (extending SPIM's set), so questions about it often merit a [mars-simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars-simulator) tag.  (For that or for quirks of its assembly syntax or its debugger.)

The problem is that [mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars) is for the "Multiple Active Result Sets" feature of Microsoft's SQL Server, and a large majority of beginner questions [mips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mips) [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) questions with a MARS tag use this [mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars), not [mars-simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars-simulator).

- [mars-simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars-simulator): 370 questions.  (Plus some that should be tagged this but aren't)
- [mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars): 117 questions, but [58 of them tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars+mips) [mips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mips) as well, and thus clearly mis-tagged.
- leaving at most 55 questions correctly tagged [mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars), i.e. [without [assembly], [mips], or [mips64]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mars+-mips+-mips64+-assembly)
- **Update after tag rename**: [a search for `[sql-server-mars] mips`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server-mars%5D%20mips) found 93 results before I started retagging, so the vast majority of questions originally tagged `[mars]` were mis-tagged, leaving only a couple dozen not mentioning MIPS.  **Perhaps something automated can be done?** Although many of them can get downvoted and hopefully roombaed as we look them over, and many others can use other edits.

And some of those 55 are mis-tagged for other reasons, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127344/python-py-earth-library-installation-failed-after-running-the-setup-py-on-window) looks like it's about the planet, not the SQL feature, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539367/using-nco-to-extracts-variables-from-a-huge-netcdf-mars3d-file) and perhaps several others seem to be about a [MARS3D climate model(?)](http://www.ifremer.fr/docmars/html/documentation.html) / file format.

**This *very* obscure tag claimed the prime real-estate, and is consistently getting consistently mis-tagged on MIPS assembly questions, when anyone bothers to use it.**  The situation would be worse if I and other users didn't retag [assembly] questions when they appear.

---

**We want typing "mars" in the tag bar will auto-complete to a tag for the MIPS simulator, and bring the ambiguity to the attention of people using it to avoid future mis-tagging for other uses.**

Suggestion:

- [mars] renamed to [sql-mars] or [ms-sql-mars] (or other name suggestions?)
- perhaps a new [mars] tag as a synonym of [mars-simulator].  (We shouldn't just rename mars-simulator to mars; that could lead to mis-tagging on other questions that aren't about the MIPS simulator.)  Or just leave it if it will auto-complete nicely.
- perhaps create a tag for MARS3D, if it merits one.

We did [recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399396/what-can-be-done-to-prevent-gas-tag-ambiguity) rename [gas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gas) to [gnu-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnu-assembler), a similar case of an obscure tag stealing the name a more popular topic wanted to use.  (In this case both tags are even more low-traffic.)

Comment: I recommend against reusing the mars moniker for the MIPS simulator, unless you want to be perpetually retagging mistagged mssql-mars questions.

Comment: @Braiam: Agreed, that's the direction I was leaning by the time I finished writing the question. But unless its popularity takes off, it's not going to be many mistagged SQL questions.  (And I personally wouldn't see such questions; I follow `[assembly]` and some other tags, but not `[mips]` or `[mars-simulator]`, and not `[sql]`.  :P But yeah, we don't want to inflict mis-tagged questions on others.)

Comment: Indeed, mars is a very ambiguous abbreviation, I immediately thought it was about [Multivariate adaptive regression splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_spline), but apparently those have only two mistagged questions.

Comment: Since the root tag is [tag:sql-server], why not [sql-server-mars]?

Comment: It is true that _MultipleActiveResultSets_ is strictly related to sql server but none prevents other ADO.NET providers to implement the same functionality. So strictly linking MARS to Sql Server could not be the right choice.

Comment: @Steve: Suggestions, then?  Like [sql-mars], or [ado-mars]?  Should I post that as an answer (along with a proposed specific course of action for starting by renaming that tag?), or do you want to do that?  I don't know anything about the feature or about ADO.NET so I'd be happy for someone else to post an answer, or a mod to just go ahead and get the ball rolling.

Comment: @Machavity: Once we decide on a name (see Steve's comment), how should we proceed?  Do you want to just go ahead and use mod tool to rename mars to sql-mars or ado-mars, or sql-server-mars, since this question has clearly gotten a positive reception?  (And can you auto-retag [mars] on all questions with any of [mips], [mips64], or [assembly] to [mars-simulator]?)  Do we want a specific course of action proposed as an answer to this question before we do anything?

Comment: @PeterCordes Once there's consensus as to what the new tag will be, a mod can rename the tag

Comment: @Machavity: Ok, as usual, naming things is the hardest part of computing. :P  So people should post answers with their tag-name suggestions so they can get voted on?  (I'm not clear on how we'll know when a consensus is reached, and if I should be doing anything to move this along, or just let it sit and wait for more comments)

Comment: Posting answer or upvoting comments is fine. We have enough Meta consensus that it needs fixing

Comment: @PeterCordes the best thing that I can think of is `ado.net-mars` We have already `ado.net-entity-data-model` and a lonely (no questions) `ado.net-data-services`

Comment: @Steve: that sounds good to me.  Thanks for finding other tags for it to be consistent with.

Comment: In the statistics domain, there's also Multi-Adaptive Regression Splines [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987899/multivariate-adaptive-regression-splinesmars-analysis)

Comment: If you have a short tag like [mars] that could conceivably mean two (or more!) completely different things, I would think that the right way to do things is have *both* sides renamed to something more explicit, and burninate the tag.

Comment: On the other hand, the answer given here kinda implies that all the questions that would be tagged for the MSSQL feature, are really duplicates of each other - in which case there isn't a need to tag [ms-sql-mars] at all.

Comment: The _other_ white meat: The `spim` [mips] simulator has _two_ tags: `spim` and `qtspim`. Nobody else is going to claim [the program name] `spim` for anything else [IMO, it's too obscure/unique]. `mars` as program name only runs into trouble because of the god/planet. To be balanced/neutral [in the `spim/mars` holy war], `mars` should be for the simulator. When I want mars/spim questions I've just looked for `mips` and ignored non-sim questions. But, if we have `spim`, we should have `mars`. It's bad enough that some only know about spim [but switch to mars after they try it].

Comment: Definitely "no" to naming it with the `ms-sql` prefix as that isn't used for any other SQL Server tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in comments, we renamed `[mars]` to `[sql-server-mars]`.  We still get a question a month or so tagged [assembly] [sql-server-mars], but often those are from users that didn't put any care into the rest of the question either, and just let "mars" auto-complete to "sql-server-mars" (unfortunately not to [mars-simulator], which is a much more popular tag, 450 questions vs. 56.)

Auto-complete for "mars" does include [mars-simulator] as the last (6th) result, in the bottom right, vs. [sql-server-mars] in the top-left right under what you typed.  I don't see any good justification for why [mars] is still a synonym of the SQL tag, not MIPS, but it's a pretty minor problem at this point.

---

**Cleanup is now complete** of questions tagged `[sql-server-mars]` and `[mips]`, or containing the string "mips" ([search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server-mars%5D%20%28%20mips%20or%20%5Bmips%5D%20%29%20%20is%3Aquestion)).  For most, I re-tagged to `[mars-simulator]`.

For a few, they were about the MIPS ISA, not specific to the toy system calls provided by MARS or to its error messages, so I removed the sql tag without replacing it.  I of course made sure questions were tagged [assembly][mips].

---

I also just **removed [sql-server-mars] from a bunch of statistics (and some astronomy) questions**.  For some of these I added `[non-linear-regression]`, I don't know if that's appropriate, but it seemed good to tag *something* so someone that knows anything about stats and R Earth package, and the Python equivalent, can find them.  [search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5Bnon-linear-regression%5D%20(mars%20%7C%20earth)) for `[non-linear-regression] (earth | mars)`.

---

The initial change of renaming [mars] to [sql-server-mars] left more questions tagged incorrectly than correctly, as I suspected.  This created significantly more work to do by hand than if we'd created a new [sql-server-mars] tag and re-tagged the SQL questions that were formerly tagged [mars].  The downside to that would have been the tag (wiki) history for [sql-server-mars], and the unnecessary edits to questions that were originally tagged correctly.

Comment: " I don't see any good justification for why [mars] is still a synonym of the SQL tag" I don't see any good justification for why it's synonym of anything at all, specially since it generates work from those that do not pay attention to those that do. Remove the synonym and you have the solutino that doesn't generate any extra unnecessary trouble.

Comment: @Braiam Or... you delete the synonym and someone makes a new [mars] tag with whatever meaning they can infuse in it. Leaving it as a synonym of something related prevents that. Trying to alter the tag blocklist is a pain (requires waiting on a Dev). I simply left it as a synonym of the original meaning. Unfortunately, typing in "mars" in the tag bar shows [sql-server-mars] first, un**mars**halling second, and [mars-simulator] last. If they'd ever [fix the tag suggestion system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387405/2370483) it would be less of an issue.

Comment: @Machavity I prefer that thousands times over having people mistagging. That means that people actually go out their way to create the tag. The [internet] tag just had to be removed *twice* in 6 years, so, being afraid of something that might happen once again and then never, is very irrational. There's a message when you are creating the tag and the 3k requirement. It's better to simply kill it every time it comes back.

Answer (score 7):

MultipleActiveResultSets is a feature available (at the moment) in the ADO.NET provider for Microsoft Sql Server. Citing [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets)

> is a feature that allows the execution of multiple batches on a single
> connection

It is not uncommon to see questions, mostly from novice .NET programmers, that are resolved adding the proper KeyValue *"MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"* in the connectionstring used to open a connection with Sql Server.

But these questions' askers hardly tag their question with `mars` exactly because they don't know that this value is required to solve their problems.

So for me there is no problem freeing the `mars` tag for something more focused and we can rename the tag to `ado.net-mars`

Comment: So, we don't need a tag for MultipleActiveResultSets? I would get behind that. But since some people use mars as MultipleActiveResultSets it also has to go.

Comment: No, I would not say so. Specific questions on MultipleActiveResultSets workings could have a tag specific for them. I proposed `ado.net-mars` with the purpose to have one independent from the actual ADO.NET provider albeit only the provider for Sql Server implements it (as far as I know)

Comment: But... that seems like a tag for literally a single boolean parameter. Is there really any benefit considering that according to even you, askers have no idea that thing exist?

Comment: Well, not all askers are unaware of it. Many ask about details on its inner workings. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374444/disadvantages-of-mars-multiple-active-result-sets?r=SearchResults&s=1|20.6642 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008867/mars-vs-nextresult?r=SearchResults&s=10|14.5202 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663939/what-effect-does-mars-have-on-nhibernate?r=SearchResults&s=35|13.0924. Some are interesting questions. Although marginal I think it is still a tag to consider

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem enough, and all of them has the bigger tag that has many answerers.

Comment: MARS is not specific to ADO.net. It is also implemented in the SQL Server native client, OLE DB and ODBC (and for example Vertica has it too). To be honest, I don't really see why this even needs a tag.

Comment: Given what Mark says above seems like if one is needed at all it might as well be `multiple-active-result-sets` - assuming a tag length of 27 chars is allowed

Comment: Per Mark's comment, I went with [sql-server-mars], but I added [ado.net-mars] as a synonym

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well, apparently we do need it. Why? I don't know.

Comment: @Machavity: Thanks.  Turns out even more of the [sql-server-mars] questions than I earlier thought are mis-tagged, though, see my edit on the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server-mars%5D+mips found 93 questions for a `[sql-server-mars] mips` search, out of 117 questions, before I started re-tagging some of those to `[mars-simulator]`, or removing the tag if it was a generic MIPS question not specific to that IDE / toy system calls.  93 is few enough to go through by hand, I guess, but if there's any automated tools a mod could apply, that might be nice.

Comment: We don't get any tag tools like that. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this. Even though MARS MIPS Simulator hasn't been updated in years, it is still widely used in Computer Architecture Courses. And therefore, users will try to add the tag on to their questions.

As MARS can relate to several different things, the question is what is more popular (not just on StackOverflow). If there is a way to make an alias for a tag or if the user entered two tags that are certainly not related, maybe a warning could pop up?

Next, if someone posts a question regarding MARS... more often than not they have an issue with MIPS assembly language and not the IDE.