# Re-tagging questions related to Unix/Linux text processing out of shell specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-tips

As a regular follower of questions around the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), and [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tags, it is really getting tough to manage (tag correct) the amount of questions that get tagged for text processing questions involving [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk), [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) or other standard tools.

The idea is to encourage using a shell agnostic tag like, [text-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) and/or [text-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting), similar to how it's implemented over Unix.SE. The [[text-formatting]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/text-formatting/info) rightly quotes it as

> Questions about using command-line utilities such as awk, sed, perl, pr, etc. to format text files.

Can we prompt adding these tags at the time of adding any of the text processing tags and leave out the shell specifics completely?

Comment: If we could at least somehow prevent askers from adding the bash tag to questions about sed/awk/grep/perl that'd be a huge step. I'm tired of retagging

Comment: They add it because they are [[tag:bash]]ing their head against the wall trying to do this text processing.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how adding a generic [[tag:text-processing]] tag would help matters. You can already get the list of latest questions with a set of tags, so having them all consolidated under a single tag is not necessary. It also seems like useful information that the asker wants to use a specific tool to accomplish the task. Why should that information not be captured in the tags?

Comment: One problem is that casual visitors select one or a few of these tools into their tags without specifying whether solutions in any of the others would also be acceptable. Conversely, if your problem is "how do I extract the third column of lines which contain 'foo' in the sixth field" how would you know to add the obvious [tag:awk] if you ... don't know?

Comment: @tripleee You'd research first and decide. *I need this in language A or language B* questions are too broad, and a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: There are ingenious id ... beginners with all kinds of flawed assumptions, we don't necessarily want to close them out just for not having reached a place where they can ask or even answer well-defined textbook questions.

Comment: To add to this problem, there is a problem with the `regex` tag also. People add it just because they can't conjure up one in `sed` or `perl` and throw the shell tags into the mix

Comment: @CodyGray: Following on oguz's lines, say user wants to do some text processing, so add the processing tag, then how do I want to achieve this? Adding a specific tag if they know is fine (e.g. `sed`) or, if they want to do that in any of `awk`, `sed`, `perl` is fine, but should leave out `shell` or `linux` completely from the mix

Comment: What if they want to do it using the shell in Linux? Why are those tags inappropriate?

Comment: @CodyGray its perfectly fine, but the problem comes when they don't stick to their original requirement. People start answering in various tags even if the question is restrictive of processing via shell. Before you know it, there are 6-7 answers on various tags  and people even retag the Q to add their own fav tags to it, making the Q completely a diff one than the original one.

Comment: @Inian if you see someone editing a question to add tags due to the answer they added then you should rollback that edit. Tags should represent the question being asked, not the answer(s) being given.

Comment: Tags are what the **question** is asking, *not* what the answers use. As an abstract example, a question on how to split a string with an ordinal position in SQL Server should not have [[tag:open-json]] added because the accepted solution uses its features to do so. Such an edit would invalidate all of the other (possible) answers, so the edit is wrong. If you want to be explicit in the rollback, select to edit the revision instead, and then put a comment in the edit reason, without changing the question content. You can also ping the editor in the comments to educate them.

Comment: If `text-processing` is required, isn't it already too broad? That is, it is a ***work order*** (*here are the requirements;  write a script for me; it doesn't matter which tool is used; thanks in advance*), not a question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen unless we stopped people from answering all together those questions, you will be hard pressed to argue against the tag.

Comment: @Braiam Not adding the tag seems like a good first/second/third/... step on the road to stopping people from answering those questions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I doubt that has stopped them from answering them in the first place the last 10+ years.

Comment: The tag [tag:text-processing] works fine on [unix.se], however it might be problematic here. In contrast to [unix.se], [so] goes beyond *ux operating systems. The tag could become to broad.

Comment: @kvantour stack overflow doesn't have any trouble with broad tags, see [tag:mathematics]

Comment: @Braiam if a PowerShell users starts using [tag:text-processing] then the aforementioned tools are not of use there. Inian states _Can we prompt adding these tags at the time of adding any of the text processing tags and leave out the shell specifics completely?_ True, but the tag cannot be used only for unix/linux tools but also beyond. Furthremore, I would even opt to avoid using the tag without any of the possible tools

Comment: @kvantour why would powershell use this tag? Text processing should be the only tag on the question because "you're not sure which tool to use", if you are unsure, you can't apply any tag at all.

Comment: @Braiam: where *UX users have `cat, tail, head`, PS users use `Get-Content` and CMD users use `type` or other tools available in the Windows Resource Kit. *UX users have `grep`, PS users use `Select-String` and CMD users use `findstr` . As you see [tag:text-formatting] might attract the wrong interest group. It should be combined with a particular OS-tag minimally, or a particular suggested tool (PS,shell,sed,...)

Comment: @kvantour again, if they are using this tag, they don't care which thing would they  use, so you can remove all tags. Also, [text formatting I've  said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408436/moving-questions-related-to-unix-linux-text-processing-out-of-shell-specific-tag?cb=1#comment849211_408439) text formatting is iffy at best. Better avoided.

Comment: @Larnu usually, I would agree with you, but this is one of those pesky exceptions. In this case is easier to identify the task than the tools used.

Comment: @oguzismail: But using `bash` for these questions ensures maximum visibility by people who know how to answer them.

Comment: @user000001 Then we should add all popular tags to our questions to achieve maximum visibility.

Comment: @oguzismail: No I specifically said *"by people who know how to answer"*, the average javascript or C# user is likely not expert in text processing with shell tools.

Comment: @user000001 And not every experienced bash user is an expert in processing textual data using tools other than bash itself. Questions tagged with bash must be about bash.

Comment: People grow into tools and ask questions about things they're unfamiliar with. Demanding foreknowledge of the full range of unix-type tools before asking a question is misguided. The site's purpose is to have easy-to-find, general, reusable solutions. A person using a Mac and its archaic version of awk or ruby can often take advantage of a solution provided for a question originating from many platforms using many tools. Tags should reflect that. An added bonus is that if people have a simple tag to watch, they will learn more.

Comment: It is counterproductive to view this as a morality issue. The current situation, which requires an array of tags (for tools, for platforms, for environments) is a unforced error and I thought, the type which unix/linux had put behind them. Even those opposed concede there are issues. For the site, it creates repetitive, low-value work. I should add that there are many great questions that have answers spanning a multitude of tools and platforms but they're all on the same subject and accessible to many more people because of that. I think that's a good thing.

Comment: I really wish this question had been tagged with the impacted tags such as sed, awk, bash, etc. so those of us who use those tags and so are impacted by the result would have been aware of it and could have voiced our opinions. At this point, 2 weeks after it was posted, it'd be pointless adding impacted tags now as no-one would see it anyway. First I became aware of this was when I noticed a question tagged with awk and with an awk answer having it's awk tag removed and unix-text-processing added instead which IMHO is not useful and then I discovered it's been happening to other questions too

Comment: @Inian it seems like your question of "Can we prompt adding these tags at the time of adding any of the text processing tags and leave out the shell specifics completely?" got interpreted as "can we create a new tag?" and answered as "yes" but I don't think that's what you were asking and it doesn't address what to do with that new tag (add along with existing tags? replace existing tags? which tags should it replace/augment - awk or bash or both or something else? and so on...). Also, when and how does any answer result in a change to SO process - an answer with 100 upvotes or something else?

Comment: Maybe it'd be useful to ask a new followup question with a specific proposal for whatever change you're suggesting and tag it with the impacted tags to get input from the people who most use those tags? I really don't know what the right way is to go about requesting/affecting change on the forum.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We're talking about the kinds of text processing you might want in / can do from a shell script.  That's a real thing, and (unless you choose to avail yourself of the shell's own built-in tools like `read` and `printf`), the shell you're using doesn't matter a lot, so [bash] isn't an ideal tag, but it's better than expecting people to tag [awk] and/or [sed].  The specific Unix tool you use doesn't matter either: you don't know ahead of time whether `grep | cut | tail` is going to be a nicer solution than `awk` or `sed`, or even `perl`, and you don't particularly care beyond possible efficiency and maintainability.

As Braiam points out, a [text-processing] tag has worked well on Unix.SE, where the context of a shell-script can be implicit from asking on that site.

On Stack Overflow, [text-processing] would probably get mis-used for questions about doing things to strings in languages like C++, C#, Java, Python, etc. in contexts that don't involve a shell script.

**I propose [unix-text-processing]** to make it more clear from the tag name alone (because tag usage guidance gets ignored a depressing amount of time when the tag name catches people's attention).   (Or possibly [shell-text-processing], although I don't like that as much.)

The name solves the ambiguity problem, and then it can do everything for SO that [text-processing] does for unix.SE.

Comment: Meh, askers misusing text-processing should just remove that tag, if there's a clear indication that a specific tool is preferred.

Comment: @Braiam: You're objecting to having tag-names imply a context, making them easy to mis-tag if people don't read the popup?  Why is that better?  Saving 5 characters in the tag name is that valuable?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the "unix" in the tag name isn't needed. MS is trying to create Linux standard tools on Windows (and also allowing Windows-only tools to run in Linux), so having a tag that encapsulates all those tools would allow the tags about those tools to be laser focused. Also, mistagging is par-of course. We just have to set the tone and maintain it for a while. Having unix in the tag name doesn't help preventing those.

Comment: @Braiam: But we have tags like [sorting] that are generic and apply whether you're doing it in C++ or a shell.  If you don't like the `unix-` in the tag name, that's reasonable, but IMO the right fix is to think of a different word, like maybe "shell".  Unix command line tools are the ancestor of this sort of text processing on other POSIX systems (like GNU/Linux), and apparently now MS Windows if you say so, but if they're compatible with Unix / POSIX then [unix-text-processing] fits as a tag name.

Comment: Yeah, those tags should go. They've not demonstrated their usefulness in the real world since it's a crapshot. Text processing would work as the only tag in the question instead, rather than with c++ or shell. And since nobody would argue that you are removing a either tag (because sorting of an array in c++ is relevant to both).

Comment: @Braiam: What tags? We don't have a [shell-text-processing] tag or [unix-text-processing] tag yet (but IMO we should, with the very name making it clear that it's not for use with [c++] or other language tags).  I'm not talking about the [shell] tag if that's what you meant.

Comment: [sorting], [searching], etc. those tags describe a task, but it's too generic and you can't argue that they should be removed of a question since "welp, they are about searching and sorting stuff, so the must have both tags". This tag is totally different to those, since by default it doesn't accept any other tag.

Comment: @Braiam: Right, I can agree those tags aren't great, and won't add much for people looking for questions to answer, or for future readers looking for answers to new questions.  But with a name like [text-processing], it's not obvious from the name itself that it's non-generic.  That's why I'm suggesting [unix-text-processing].  It would be better if everyone read tag popups so the name alone didn't need to do that work, but we live in the real world.  My proposal is to accept a name that's longer than we'd like, and includes the word "unix" when it can apply elsewhere, to save retagging work.

Comment: I would save that for a next iterations. I would use 15 minutes myself every day to make sure the usage is correct. But I can't see right now how it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Braiam: You'd rather spend 15 minutes every day retagging mis-tagged questions, instead of coming up with a tag name that prevents most mis-tagging?  Much better to anticipate the problem ahead of time, if we can come up with a satisfactory tag name.

Comment: No, because mistagging is inevitable (with your proposal or mine). The 15 minutes day is to set the tone and make sure everyone understands how the tag is used and they also start to enforce it. I'm just going to be the small snowball to create the bigger one.

Comment: @Braiam: Of course it's inevitable, but a well-crafted tag name can significantly *reduce* mis-tagging.  For example, that's why [we renamed \[mars\] to \[sql-server-mars\]]([Tag rename: \[mars\] to \[ms-sql-mars\], so \[mars\] can be about the MIPS simulator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406220))).  This case may not be as clear-cut as that (where that entirely stemmed the tide of mis-tagged mars-simulator questions), but I expect it will help significantly.  It's better not to have to edit in the first place.

Comment: One thing is about an ambiguous tag that has multiple meanings in the same context, this tag doesn't really hit that. There's nobody that would confuse text-processing with c, php, msqls-server, etc.

Comment: @Braiam: I feel like you're being disingenuous, or at least missing my point.  Of course nobody would use it *instead* of a tag like [c] or [php]; that wasn't what I was trying to avoid.  But someone who hadn't read the tag description popup might well tag it *along side* [c].  But I think that would be a lot less likely if it was named [unix-text-processing].

Comment: And as I said several times before "you can remove every tag of the question and nobody would argue with you" because the tag specifically disallow this.

Comment: @Braiam: I don't understand what you're even saying with that last comment.  SO requires questions to have at least one tag, doesn't it?  Also, I don't see how the ability to remove tags from existing questions have anything to do with discouraging new users from tagging them where they're not appropriate.

Comment: I give up. It seems that you are lost on your own argument so let me put it this way: sed, awk, perl, etc. have a problem. People argue which tags should questions about these should have. A new tag would solves that problem. The new tag should be the only tag on the question. Everyone wins. Prepending unix doesn't make the solution more likely, as mistagging is inevitable but would be at least manageable.

Comment: @Braiam: I agree with you on everything except the idea that the tag-name *should* include something to make it less generic.  [unix-text-processing], [shell-text-processing], [script-text-processing], or something like that would *reduce* (not eliminate) use of that tag where it *shouldn't* be used.  They wouldn't help people find it in the first place to use instead of [sed]  [awk], or [bash].  I agree that [unix-text-processing] isn't a perfect name, but considering the tradeoffs, I like it better than [text-processing].

Comment: @Braiam: You've repeatedly asserted that mis-use of a [text-processing] tag (if it existed) wouldn't be a problem, or that people could spend time every day fixing [c], [python], etc. questions where someone used it. The only argument to support that claim which I think you've made is that mis-tagging is inevitable. But mis-tagging isn't a binary phenomenon - the *rate* of mis-tagging (and the amount of work to fix it) is a continuous variable.  When I tried to discuss that, your replies stopped making any sense.

Comment: As one of the top answerers of questions tagged awk, sed, or grep on SO I'm disappointed that I had no idea this discussion had happened as it's not tagged with those or any other impacted tool and then today I discovered we now have people running around SO **replacing** the awk and sed tags with just the unix-text-processing tag. That's a good way to ensure that awk and sed experts never see the questions.

Comment: @EdMorton: Hrm, that's a good point.  Probably for a transition period, we should just be *adding* [unix-text-processing] to new questions.  Probably you should ping @ inian who asked this question in the first place.  I just suggested this tag name, and haven't been involved with any re-tagging.  (I didn't even notice my meta answer had been accepted until I got your comment notification.)  Maybe a mod can get this Q&A re-added to the hot meta sidebar to increase visibility now that a decision has been made?  Maybe with an update section in the question.

Comment: @EdMorton: You might want to post that comment as an answer to this meta question, or ask a new meta question about how to handle the transition without hiding questions from people who don't follow meta.

Comment: @PeterCordes has a decision been made? How did that happen? I see a question with 11 upvotes and an accepted answer with 12 (which just means the person who asked the question and a few others liked it) and somehow that tiny number of participants has resulted in significant changes to SO with no input from any significant number of people who'd be impacted by that change. I don't understand how we got to that point.

Comment: @EdMorton: I have no idea, I was assuming that a decision had been made based on your first comment about people already retagging.  Like I said, I haven't interacted with this Q&A, or any questions with [sed]/[awk] tags, since Jun 19th or so.  I *use* GNU/Linux on my desktop so I understand the subject, but I don't follow it on SO, and only occasionally see a HNQ on that subject on unix.SE.

Comment: @EdMorton: sounds like it's time for a new meta question about (1) can we hold off on actually retagging until word gets around.  (2) how to get word around.  (3) Based on votes on this meta, consensus seems to be in favour of having a tag like [text-processing] in some form, although you could ask for a way to get more attention on this meta for people to vote up / down and post new answers.

Comment: But we don't even know if anyone cares or agrees that there's a problem yet. The question has 11 and your answer 12 upvotes - that's hardly a consensus of people impacted by this proposed change. I'd guess that, like you, almost no-one voting on this actually participates in the impacted tags on SO. I'm not criticizing your response or anything, you're welcome to your opinion of course. I'd really like whoever wants this change to push for participation and acceptance rather than me have to do it.

Comment: @EdMorton: I hadn't made any major decisions or tag corrections since this post, but kept removing the `bash` tag out of text processing questions, like I used to do before this. This post was mainly to discuss the issue and look out for open thoughts

Comment: @Inian understood but then it would've been good to tag the question with the tags impacted by it to get input from the people impacted by it. Right now it's been asked, has an accepted answer (from someone who doesn't participate in the tags on SO), and people are taking action on it and I doubt if the tiniest fraction of people impacted by it even know the question was asked, never mind had an opportunity to voice an opinion on it. sed and awk questions being retagged with unix-text-processing are effectively disappearing into a black hole.

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't think it works to use the `[sed]` tag on *meta* questions.  That won't get the attention of people who follow that tag on the main site.  I don't know of a good mechanism to do that.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assumed because it was all stackoverflow.com.... Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 18):

In Unix and Linux we have a generic text-processing tag. It has been glorious. We stopped arguing about whenever should we add/remove sed, awk, zsh, perl, tr, etc. because at the end of the day, the asker doesn't care what they use, just that they solve the underlying problem. It's the XY problem all again, just that the Y is a red herring about using a specific tool when any tool would work, and we can't decide which tag to apply (on some questions we argued that it should have *every tag*). So, instead of having 5 tags, we used 1 tag **identifying the task rather than the tool**.

This has shifted tool tags to be actually about the specific tools. When introduced we didn't back fill all the questions to use the tag instead, so that's why it isn't still the biggest tag on the site. But it has been one of the most helpful at stopping us from having long and unproductive discussions about whenever to add a tag or not just because the asker accepted the answer in awk while he was asking for a sed solution.

The tag wiki says:

> Use this tag when your question is about processing text files and you're not sure which tool to use. If your question is about a specific tool, use its tag. If your question is about multiple tools, include this tag and the tags for the other tools.
>
> When asking a text processing question, you should always
>
> - Explain the task you need to do
> - include a reasonable part of your input file (preformatted by indenting with four whitespaces)
> - include the expected output for this input data (also formatted)
> - give your attempt to solve the problem and what didn't work (this is *not* to embarrass you, it helps to give an explanation for the solution, so you'll learn to help yourself next time)

Comment: But Unix.SE has limited tools for text processing, while on SO it's also possible to use Python, Java, C#, [insert your favorite programming language] to process text outside of shell-based tools. Are we okay with answers for any programming language?

Comment: @AndrewT. well, at least you have specific tags for those tools, like [tag:python], [tag:java] etc. and people removes them where it doesn't make sense. Here is about a task "processing text with whatever tool I have at our disposal". BTW, on UL we use python, perl, etc. where it makes sense (and we can make safe assumptions that those tools are available). It's not as if we will replace java with this tag just because it's processing text. It's a tag for "processing text files and **you're not sure which tool to use.**"

Comment: The part I don't like about this seems adequately expressed well by the "you're not sure which tool to use" part - it means the question has not put down even the bare minimum of narrowing down the problem. I don't see how such questions can be about *specific issues*; rather, the scope is automatically about writing an entire solution/program from scratch. That is not something I feel should be encouraged by having tags for it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well, that's the lesser evil rather than having a discussion under every question because OP asked for a sed solution and accepted an awk answer.

Comment: @Braiam I could not disagree more. If people create bad content, the response should not be to declare that as the new standard.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well, try to police that.

Comment: @Braiam I do try. That's why I am not at all cool with requests to sabotage what quality criteria there are. Because *someone* is going to smugly point at this meta here and be all "stack overflow doesn't have any trouble with broad questions, see the text-processing tag".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I would instead choose my battles, for example [regex]. We literally got moderators against curators and siding with reopen drivel questions. At least this way we get low quality shoved into something else that isn't regex.

Comment: @Braiam So because [regex] works so well, let's introduce *[regex] 2: free for all*? At least this way we can officially endorse low quality question. - Sorry, not interested in buying that bridge. I vastly prefer preventing battles.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no, **regex doesn't work**. That's the point. Text processing would be better than regex in the way that you can remove every tag of the question and nobody  would  argue with you. With the regex tag, the quality bleeds to other tags. Text processing by default won't allow this (obviously policing it, but the tag  wiki already implies that no other tag  must be used).

Comment: @Braiam The point is that the problem is not bad quality bleeding into other tags, the problem is endorsing bad quality full stop. This *will* creep back into other tags, as it can be used to justify other exemptions - like, you know, [you did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408436/moving-questions-related-to-unix-linux-text-processing-out-of-shell-specific-tag/408438?noredirect=1#comment849257_408436). I don't much care whether we might agree that [text-processing] smells twice or half as much as [regex] - it should not smell at all.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi quality is easier assured when you don't have users deliberately boycotting one another, like the regex tag does. It's about removing pointless arguments. I didn't see you arguing against [science area tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314838), like I did. So yes, I know what I'm arguing about. Apparently you don't. [I have exceptions to my rules where they make sense](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300700/792066). This is one of them.

Comment: @Braiam "So yes, I know what I'm arguing about. Apparently you don't." Pardon? Are you sure you want to go that route just because I don't argue against everything you argue against? No, I did not speak up against things *before I was even active on Meta*. No, even today I do not speak up against everything – be it out of interest to not be burned at the stake by antropomorphic vegetables, lack of time, or simply upvoting someone who did it better than me. I am speaking up here and now. If your reasoning boils down "because Braiam says so", that's indeed a pointless argument.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, I want to argue that route because you seem to be fixed in creating straw mans. I've already presented evidence and how it should work. Your worries are misplaced in this discussion, because the quality of the questions aren't solely dependent on the tags. These questions are asked anyways, with whatever tag the asker consider applicable. This would remove these kind of questions from these tags. Afterwards, you can start trying to manage the quality of these questions, but at least the other tags would be more useful for their users.

Comment: By evidence, I assume you mean the tag on Unix.SE? I don't see how that is evidence - the thing that makes it useful there seems to be contrary to what would it take to be useful on [so]. I am not saying quality depends on tags. I am not saying not having these tags would make the questions go away. I am not denying these tags might clear the main tags. What I do oppose is the idea to quarantine these questions and fix the issue later on - because the suggested quarantine would legitimate this content; there is nothing to fix once we accept that content as being okay.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi well, which tag you propose to use for questions where the user uses sed and accepts an answer in awk? How you propose that experts don't get into arguments removing/retagging stuff? How do you solve those problems that exist on the SO and that UL solved?

Comment: @Braiam sed, a Meta Q&A on the actual problem, I don't know but making things worse is not a solution either.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi how this would make it worse? For the tags sed/awk/shell/etc. it would be a boon. Yes, it doesn't address your quality argument but it makes those tags easier to manage.

Comment: @Braiam Shifting content between tags is at best a zero sum game – the stuff is going to end up somewhere. But in specific, I feel it would make things worse because it would legitimate this bad content as a desirable category. I feel it would make things worse because it creates (another?) precedent that people can point to and say "why can they post turds but not us?". Seeing what the regex tag is used to justify is bad enough already...

Comment: This is horrible idea. If someone needs to process text and doesn't even know where to start, which tool to use, is standard definition of too broad, unclear and write my code questions.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar well, we already have questions like that on a plethora of tags. So, better dive right into it. Start with [tag:sed], [tag:awk], [tag:shell], [tag:bash], [tag:perl].

Comment: So what is the problem? Vote to close them. Yes, I know not all will get closed, but I don't see how having a tag solves anything here.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar it's about reclaiming those tags for their actual purpose. Also, you are getting dangerously close to regex territory because some people would start a storm if we close them. Maybe the discussion you all seem missing is asking "is completing a task without specifying with what should be completed on topic?"

Comment: @Braiam How do you make people actually use this tag? It's not obvious at all that you don't just stamp whatever tools you use like in other cases and start looking for something different god-knows-what.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev just put it on questions. [People don't have problem finding it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/654329/1). If they can't, we could [just add it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/654890/revisions)

Comment: @Braiam 'Maybe the discussion you all seem missing is asking "is completing a task without specifying with what should be completed on topic?"' This very Meta question is missing to ask that, but just assumes "yes" and offers a solution to follow-up problems.

Answer (score 6):

Nice question but I am afraid I'm a little confused.
Is the Question the problem or the proposal? I honestly think that your last question at the bottom is the most reasonable proposal, kind of a request for automation. But the question/title seems to be the activity that brought you here

I do not think that **text-formating** is appropriate as shell agnostic because it is too much generic, it could be web, mobile, desktop, UI, design I don't know it doesn't feel descriptive and specific at the same time, it's a huge category (the name, the description looks great).

By the other hand terminal:

> A terminal or command-line interface is a text-only interface for
> interacting with an operating system or a piece of software. A user
> typically types commands into the terminal to perform specific tasks.

does not tell me much..  is it sed avaiable in PowerShell?, do not forget how useful keywords are I mean if I am looking for specificity I will include them.

I don't see an easy answer:

- In example, if adding the sed keyword automatically removes every shell tag which includes/support sed by default (or perl I am out of my area) will not be a benefit for the user performing a search like "bash, text-formatting ... regex, whatever"
- Change the tag name? I think that tag is missing the word terminal but at the same time sed is not tied to just terminals right? You could use it in your program and allow the user to perform actions with a textbox.

I am not sure if that have sense for you but is that your point? most of the people will use sed and perl keywords in the context of a terminal so it is redundant but specific and necessary.

I know this does not add much value to the discussion but that is the point, I cannot confirm nor deny if this is convenient but I see what you are trying to do. Thank you for contributing

Comment: Yeah, text formatting is iffi at best. Text processing on the other hand... :)

Comment: You are totally right, it sounds good

Comment: However, I'm still not sure about removing `terminal`. I know the question is about bash, shell, etc., but those are keywords that avoid the bottleneck that separates people who understand the underlying problem and semantics from those who are new to programming or are not very good with the language

Comment: We shouldn't really rely on tags to be a proxy of how much an asker knows about the topic. If you find a tag that has nothing to do with the issue in the question, just remove it.

Comment: That is exactly the point. Over the years I have used regular expressions but a few months ago I had to use `sed` (first time) and it was great. But all this years I didn't need it. So there are this scenarios: you can "follow" specific tags as a helper to filter what you are looking for, but more generic tags could open your mind to do things different or use new tools. So good luck with this discussion :D

Answer (score 1):

We could decide that **questions like this are off-topic for Stack Overflow**, and should be asked on Unix.SE with the [text-processing] tag.

A question like "I have this Unix text processing problem, but I don't know which tool to pick from the Unix command-line toolbox" doesn't lend itself well to any existing tag on SO, and [one can argue that it's kind of a "work order"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408436/moving-questions-related-to-unix-linux-text-processing-out-of-shell-specific-tag?cb=1#comment849200_408436), especially if there isn't an example implementation that someone's trying to clean up / streamline.

To be fair, we already have the [regex] tag where people who enjoy regexing basically solve one-off custom requests like this, despite their low future applicability.  At least they serve as good examples of how to use various features of tools, and sometimes of neat tricks.

The major downside of this option is closing (or migrating if in good shape otherwise) every new question on SO in this category.  It's not one of the vote-to-migrate site options, and closing isn't great for  people asking the questions.

(Of course, questions that don't clearly define the problem or otherwise wouldn't be good questions even on unix.SE should be closed, not migrated.  But probably most questions will get closed not migrated anyway: vote-to-migrate to superuser is already an option, but even questions in ok shape typically get closed instead.)

Comment: (I'm in favour of creating a [unix-text-processing] tag on SO to collect these questions, but it seems to me this is the other logical alternative.  Trying to treat existing [sed] / [awk] questions as open to answers with any shell-script text-processing tool is likely to not work well, more likely for answers to end up trying to explain how sed works instead of just using awk for something that would be easier in awk.)

Comment: I think this proposal needs some more justification. **Why would these questions be off-topic for Stack Overflow?** We don't declare questions to be off-topic here simply because there is another site that might accept them. Some overlap between scope of the different SE sites is natural and unavoidable. Topicality isn't determined by "where else can this go?", it is determined by, "does it fit within *this site's* scope". I think shell scripting certainly does fit within SO's scope.

Comment: @CodyGray "I have this Unix text processing problem, but I don't know which tool to pick from the Unix command-line toolbox" is standard definition for too broad, unclear, and write my code kind of question. It is simply off-topic for SO.

Comment: Oh, so only questions where the asker doesn't know what tool they want to use are off-topic? I suppose I can get behind that.

Comment: @CodyGray: Agreed.  When writing a shell script, the various tools like sed and awk are very analogous to the various Python or perl modules available when writing a Python or perl program.  Would we close a Python question as off-topic because the asker hasn't already picked a Python module or two for their list-manipulation / looping / data-structure problem?  Or which kind of loop they want to use in C++?  Of course not.  I don't agree with this answer, I just split it off from my other answer as requested, because it's the logical alternative.

Comment: I would say that it is possible to have question that is well written, on topic, but the OP is using wrong tool for the job. We allow such questions and answers can offer better approach or tools, unless question specifically states there is some specific reason why some tool, library or whatever cannot be used.

Comment: There's a difference between being uncertain as to which Python module to use, versus being uncertain which programming language you want to use. The former is sufficiently narrowly scoped; the latter is not (far, far too broad). I'm not sure which category these questions fall into. Arguably, since it's all the Unix shell ecosystem, all of the tools are available, so it doesn't matter which one is used, just like any Python module can be used when writing Python code. In that case, I don't see how this would be too broad or unclear. Unless, you know, the *specific question* is.

Answer (score -3):

A generic tag that replaces the specific tags is not useful, and might actually be harmful.

---

Let me start with:
**There is nothing wrong with answering a question with a "different tag" technology, as long as it can be reasonably inferred to be available.**

When a question is about using a tool *to solve a problem*, it is fine to point out the tool is not appropriate/ideal *for the problem* and offer a different approach. This is not restricted to text-processing – it is the same as proposing a different data type, a different library, a different algorithm, or a different programming paradigm.
In any of such cases, there are two important things of note for this:

- The question asker does not have to anticipate the solution. They do not have to know their approach is flawed, and that a more generic approach is needed.
- The question topic and problems do not change. People with a similar issue will still search for the issue, not the answer.

Neither the asker nor the answerer should change the question tag to reflect the solution. *Tags exist to categorise questions*, not answers.

**Just because some questions can/should be *answered* generically is not a reason to tag them generically.** By extension, it is not enough to motivate having a generic tag.

If the problem is formulated using/for a specific tool, then it should be tagged with it.

---

When people ask an [*on-topic* question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about practical issues like text processing, then they already have a *programming* problem – meaning they already have committed to a tool. This is not comparable to the situation on, say, Unix.SE, where [the text-procssing tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/text-processing/info) says

> Use this tag when your question is about processing text files and **you're not sure which tool to use.**

Selecting a tool in the context of text processing is the absolute basis to even having a programming problem, and basic [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) should turn up candidates for tasks that can be solved by "[awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk), [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) or other standard tools". If a question asker is not sure which tool to use*, then there is an extremely high chance the question is off-topic.

**There should not be tags that endorse asking off-topic questions.**

* Even if what they are sure about turns out to be wrong.

---

Now, of course there are going to be some questions tagged [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), or [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), or any other tag, when these tags are not appropriate to the specific question. They might be tagged too broadly, or too tightly, or with unrelated tags.

Problem is: **If people are mishandling tags, then more tags is not going to fix that.**

People use the wrong tags because they do not know better tags exist, or they do not know tag wikis exist, or they just do not care. Adding a "more correct" tag will not let them know that tag exists, it will not let them know what is written in tag wikis, it will not make them care.
It will just add another tag that can be used wrong.

When folks are having an issue piping things through `sed` in `bash` on `linux`, then [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux)[bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)[sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) is just much more obvious to use than [unix-text-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-text-processing).

---

As some comments and answers to this question argue, there is a hint of using such a tag to *quarantine the trash*, so to speak.

That is not the point of tags. If the kind of trash is okay, then it is okay in any tag. If the kind of trash is not okay, then it should not be declared okay-but-only-over-there.
If there is a significant issue with trash that should not exist in the first place, *we need to talk about **that**, darling*. Not apply a bandaid.

Comment: Nah, this is counter-productive. There is a concrete problem at hand, there is also a super easy way to resolve it for good, and you're opposing it by denying the problem's existence.

Comment: @oguzismail I don't think I did, but please feel free to clarify what problem you think I denied exists.

Comment: "A generic tag that replaces the specific tags is not needed" what specific tag would be this replacing?

Comment: Are you trying to railroad people writing shell scripts into having already picked on tool from the toolbox?  The thing they're actually programming is a shell script.  If your real argument is that *if* that's what you're doing, and you *haven't* picked a tool yet, your question is off topic for SO and should be asked on Unix.SE, that's fine, but I think you could state that more clearly.

Comment: @Braiam "Can we prompt adding these tags at the time of adding any of the text processing tags and leave out the shell specifics completely?"

Comment: But you also argue that answering with a different command-line tool can work despite someone already deciding they think they want a `sed` answer.  Is your point there that a [sed] question should already have an attempt using `sed`?  Yes, questions should include an attempt, but tagging [sed] sounds like a recipe for shoehorning the problem into sed even if it would actually be much easier to do in awk.  (e.g. because the answers focus on fixing the sed attempt and teaching how sed works.)

Comment: @PeterCordes RE [your first comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408436/re-tagging-questions-related-to-unix-linux-text-processing-out-of-shell-specific/408474?noredirect=1#comment849516_408474): Yes, such questions being off-topic is my point – I do not want to suggest a specific SE as an alternative (similar to how CodeReview isn't always a good target for improvement questions), so I don't see how I could state that more clearly. I felt that "If a question asker is not sure which tool to use*, then there is an extremely high chance the question is off-topic." makes it clear.

Comment: @PeterCordes RE [your second comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408436/re-tagging-questions-related-to-unix-linux-text-processing-out-of-shell-specific/408474?noredirect=1#comment849519_408474): If someone explicitly says in their question they want a ``sed`` answer, then no specific or generic tag is going to change that. If the question is tagged [sed], that doesn't mean they need a ``sed`` answer no matter what. As a comparison, in the [tag:python] we often have people use and tag the ``threading`` library when they actually need the ``multiprocessing`` library instead. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] And in such cases, there is no issue with an answer pointing out why the other library should be used instead and how to do it. So if the issue is that there is a feeling that "[sed] tag requires ``sed`` answers", then that's a very different policy at least compared to the tags I frequent. I would much rather see a consensus on which policy is proper before modifying/creating tags.

Comment: My point is that some answerers are probably going to treat it that way (or lean that direction a bit) based on the [sed] tag in the question, rather than just a generic tag with a `sed` attempt.  Even without any positive statement that it has to be with sed.  I might be wrong, of course, but that's my best guess.  Of course not everyone will treat it that way.  I don't follow the tag myself so possibly my concern is misplaced, and it's not a problem in practice.  (I think having questions like this tagged [sed] or [awk] is the current situation.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I know there are people interpreting tags as such. But I'd rather have a Meta Q&A that documents consensus on whether question tags are binding for the answer, or whether reasonably close equivalents can be used. Otherwise, we need *a lot* of such generic tags.

Comment: That general text processing questions are tagged with bash, zsh, ksh, sh, shell, etc. is the problem. You're saying it's not, that's what I understand from your answer. RE one of your comments above, both `threading` and `multiprocessing` are python libraries; sed and awk on the other hand, are different **programming languages**. You're comparing apples to oranges there.

Comment: @oguzismail I am challenging the proposed solution, not the problem. But yes, I see that I should add something to the shell issue itself (the question might need clarification as well, by the way - it's not entirely obvious whether it is about replacing the shell tags or the awk/sed/perl/... tags or both with the generic tag).

Comment: @oguzismail wrt the Python libraries not being comparable to the shell programs: I disagree. In the context of writing scripts, shell programs might as well be libraries. If it's clear the code is not part of some larger awk/sed/perl/... code but a part of a shell script/pipeline, it's just another modular part that can be replaced. FWIW, I actually think having a shell/OS tag makes this *clearer*.

Comment: No. If we allow that, and we currently do, one who knows any of those languages can easily earn a golden badge in the bash tag without answering a single genuine bash question. It doesn't make any sense. Besides, snippets written in many interpreted languages can be embedded in a shell script, it's not limited to awk, sed, and perl. As for bash, there is no guarantee that it be accompanied by standard UNIX tools, you can have bash installed on your computer and not have any of those utilities; so, what you call *shell programs* are not necessarily standard bash libraries.

Comment: @oguzismail look, I get that you don't like the current status quo. As said, I don't disagree about there being a problem. But almost none of what you listed is solved by the proposed tag - with the exception of getting a badge. But that is common in many other tags, most prominently regex. A [text-XXX] tag would say even less about which "shell programs" (better with the quotes?) are expected or available. (If the "standard bash libraries" part was about the comparison to python libraries I made earlier - I could just as well have picked third party libraries.)

Comment: Third party or not, they are still written to be used with python, right? But each of bash, sed, awk, etc. is a standalone interpreter with its own language. So they can't be compared to python libraries. [unix-text-processing] tag would say that those which are meant for processing text files among the utilities listed [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) are available. Regex questions is another, greater problem that deserves its own thread.

Comment: @oguzismail If we were talking about using bash, sed, awk etc as "standalone interpreters", then most of what has been said here would be moot. If we cannot switch one for the other, having a super tag is moot. If it's a problem specific to *only one* of these then *all of* [bash], [shell], [linux], **and** [unix-text-processing] are just wrong tags. But here we are with people complaininghow sed gets answered with awk and whatnot because these things *are* actually interchangeable for the issue. If it quacks like a library, it is a library. I can add scare quotes if it helps.

Comment: No, no. What we're saying here is, a question that is about sed, and a question that can be answered with a sed answer (i.e a text processing question) should be distinguishable; none of those programs always quack like a library whatever that means, hence the proposal for the super tag. Now if you're saying the latter is too broad for SO, yeah, that's something I can agree with.

Comment: This answer makes me wonder why we allow more than one tag on a question? The reality is that some things are complicated. By design, there are multiple tools on multiple platforms which do overlapping things. Overtagging isn't the solution. If refining the tagging system has improved matters on another similar site, then it bears consideration here.